# How to find a specific file in windows using command prompt

Tags: windows, command

I would like to search for a file on my windows C drive for a specific file, file.pdf using command prompt, How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I open "Find Files" dialog from command-line in Windows XP to search a specific folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95432/how-do-i-open-find-files-dialog-from-command-line-in-windows-xp-to-search-a-sp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, go to the drive you want to search. E.g if you are already in C type cd /.. to go to the root directory or otherwise type `cd <directory name>` (e.g `cd D:`)

Type `dir /s file.pdf` to search for that specific file.

Windows will list all the files with that name giving the path to it.