# Free alternative(s) to PowerGREP

Tags: windows, regex, grep, utility

First of all, great praise goes out to [PowerGREP](http://www.powergrep.com/). It's a great program.

But it's not free. Some of its options I'm looking for:

- Being able to use .NET regexp's (or similar) to find things in a filtered list of files through subdirectories.
- Replacing that stuff with other regexps.
- Being able to jump to that part of the file in some sort of editor.
- Non commandline.
- Being able to copy the results / filename and occurrences of the text.
- Low overhead would also be nice, so not too many dependencies, etc.
- And I need it on Windows.

Comment: https://easygrep.com is a free lightweight grep - simular to PowerGREP but just does the basics.

Comment: Similar: *[What are good grep tools for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/)*

Answer (score 19):

I would suggest trying the [new dnGrep](https://dngrep.github.io/). It's a .NET application that provides grep-like functionality and has almost all the features you specified.

Here are the features and a sample screenshot:

- Shell integration (ability to search from [Windows Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer))
- Plain text/regex/[XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) search (including case-insensitive search)
- Phonetic search (using Bitap and Needleman-Wunch algorithms)
- File move/copy/delete actions
- Search inside archives (via plug-ins)
- Search [Microsoft Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word) documents (via plug-ins)
- Search PDF documents (via plug-ins)
- Undo functionality
- Optional integration with a text editor (like [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B))
- Bookmarks (ability to save regex searches for the future)
- Pattern test form
- Search result highlighting
- Search result preview
- Does not require installation (can be run from a USB drive)

[image: dnGrep screenshot]

Comment: Great tool, previously using GrepWin have switched of to this now.

Comment: Just saved me a bunch of money from buying PowerGrep. This tools seems really neat!

Comment: Time-saver when searching through PDF files.

Answer (score 14):

Feature-wise nothing even comes close to PowerGREP, so the question is, how many compromises are you willing to make? I agree that PowerGREP's price tag is a bit steep (not that I have ever regretted a single penny I spent on it), so perhaps something cheaper might do?

[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com) is an excellent text editor with very good regex support. It supports Perl-style regular expressions, and you can do find/replace operations in multiple (optionally pre-filtered) files with it. I'd say it can do everything you want to do according to your question.

[image: UE screenshot]

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com), apart from being the best regex editor/debugger on the market, also has a limited GREP functionality, allowing search/replace in (pre-filtered) subdirectories. It's also not free, but considerably less expensive than PowerGREP, and its regex engine has all the features you could ask for (the current version even introduced recursive regexes, and the extremely useful ability to translate regexes between flavors). Big pluses here are the ability to do a non-desctructive preview for all operations, and to have backups automatically be created of all files that are modified during a grep.

[image: RB screenshot]

Comment: I did wonder if Regex Buddy could be used as a poor man's PowerGrep.

Comment: Unfortunately, UltraEdit (or rather, the company behind it) is now pushing the subscription model very hard (it is ***impossible*** to find out from their descriptions whether the software will continue to work after the subscription runs out or if it is only to get access to new versions - they may do this deliberately to create some FUD). It is also [extremely buggy on Linux](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/03/29/using-geany/).

Answer (score 11):

I use [GrepWin](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html) extensively during development and on production servers - it doesn't support all the features you specify, but it gets the job done (your mileage may vary).

Comment: great answer, thanks, just used GrepWin to find config files only in my deploy folders, while ignoring those in Debug and Release folders, and now dragging that list of filse into Visual Studio for editing. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: grepWIn is pretty quick and it does replaces, what is lacks is a Replace window to check you results (and built in regexes), which is essential in my experience.

Answer (score 7):

For a fast loading, fast executing program used to only *find* (no search and replace) then I've found [Baregrep](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baregrep/) to be pretty good. It does subdirectories.

Answer (score 4):

You might have a look on this:

*[Open Source PowerGREP Alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/powergrep/?license=opensource)*

Currently there're six alternatives to PowerGREP.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know PowerGREP, but [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin) lets you search regexes in directories.

Comment: The link seems to be broken - hangs and times out after a few minutes: *"The connection has timed out. The server at tools.tortoisesvn.net is taking too long to respond."*

Answer (score 1):

Get [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) for a bunch of free alternatives!
grep, sed, awk, perl, python... goes on.
But, oops! you want to stick to GUI.

I always wonder at how people wrap GUI around things like grep and get cash for that!

---

[WinGrep](http://www.wingrep.com/index.htm) seems to be free though and, yet comes with quite a punch.

> Windows Grep is designed for searching plain-ASCII text files, such as program source, HTML, RTF and batch files, but it can also search binary files such as word processor documents, databases, spreadsheets and executables.

Comment: Well powergrep goes far beyond a simple grep, it is compatible with several engiens, offers a complete documentation , regex libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can get [GNU grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) or [Gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).

Comment: Those are command line utilities, which Mischa says he doesn't want.