# Is there a Pattern Matching Utility like GREP in Windows?

Tags: windows, grep

Is there a similar utility to `grep` available from the Windows Command Prompt, or is there a third party tool for it?

Comment: See [this canonical thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tools-for-windows).

Comment: as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/87382/6908282)- [grepWin](https://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html) &  [PowerGrep](http://www.powergrep.com) are good options.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also found one more way of utilizing GREP like functionality in Windows 7 and above without any extra application to install and on older systems you can use install Powershell.

In [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx), User can use [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) it has quite comprehensive set of feature that provides all the functionality of GREP plus more.

Hope It helps.

Answer (score 266):

There is a command-line tool called `FINDSTR` that comes with all Windows NT-class operating systems (type `FINDSTR /?` into a Command Prompt window for more information) It doesn't support everything `grep` does but it might be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Thanks!  It's not grep, but I like to be able to function without installing additional software on other people's machines and this will let me.

Comment: You can also use it with the pipe symbol, e.g. `netstat -n | FINDSTR 3389`

Comment: @sage, with some creativity, **findstr** works exactly like grep. Refer to this [grep for Windows example](http://www.mkyong.com/linux/grep-for-windows-findstr-example/).

Comment: @mkyong - I agree.  I did not mean to suggest that it is somehow incomplete, just that it is different and using more tools requires more work.  That being said, findstr is my tool of choice now when using others' computers, but I have to refresh my memory on syntax every time I use it.

Comment: @gonzobrains: It's just not that well documented. As far as I can tell, it's always been available from the Windows NT command prompt-- certainly, it was available in Windows NT 4 but I don't know about Windows 3.5x. The command prompt was considered such a "second class citizen" by Microsoft back then that lots of useful command-line utilities have been overlooked in the documentation ☹️

Answer (score 42):

PowerShell (included as standard on Windows 7/2008R2, optional for XP/2003/Vista/2008) which includes the `select-string` cmdlet for this purpose.

Comment: While Select-String (alias:sls) uses regular expressions it doesn't support some basic features like directory recursion.  For that you need to combine multiple PowerShell commands.  Like "dir -R -Include *.txt | sls "^My Regex String$"

Comment: It's hundreds of characters to do very common excludes: like node_modules and .git. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294836/how-can-i-exclude-multiple-folders-using-get-childitem-exclude

Answer (score 35):

[Grep for Windows by GnuWin Project](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) (2014-10-02: It's outdated, see comments below)

Comment: This is the GnuWin32 grep.  It hasn't been updated to the newest version of grep.  For that you'll have to get the Cygwin version.  See comment below.

Answer (score 30):

as mentioned, findstr works fine. example :

C:>dir | findstr Windows

11/06/2013  09:55 PM              Windows

Answer (score 14):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned [FINDSTR](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true). I'm no grep poweruser, but findstr does what I need it to, filter files and stdin, with some primitive regex support. Ships with Windows and all that. (Edit: Well someone did mention findstr, It's late I guess)

Answer (score 11):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) grep and more ;)

Comment: You don't have to install the entire Cygwin package to run Cygwin grep.  You just need about 5 DLL's:cygpcre-0.dll, cygpcreposix-0.dll, cygwin1.dll, cygintl-8.dll, and cyggce_s-1.dll.

Comment: I use Cygwin for a long time...  and recently try to substitute with Windows-Linux-Subsystems... not for long... BACK TO CYGWIN... much more rich and less more intrusive... just add <cygwin>\bin to the path... and you can use it anyware in Windows/Batch/Powershell... in s DOS-Box... in a Powershell-Box... etc. etc.--- GREAT TOOL!!!

Answer (score 6):

[GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) is worth mentioning, it provides native Win32 version of all standard linux tools, including grep, file, sed, groff, indent, etc.

And it's constantly updated when new versions of these tools are released.

Comment: It now seems to be available on choclatey, so    _cinst GnuWin32_   works to install it quickly.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows I use [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/) for file search. BSD licensed, works in console, saves time on typing cmdline parameters. Here is its search dialog invoked by Alt-F7. [image: Alt-F7]

Answer (score 4):

[UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) is a great set of Unix utilites that run on Windows.  It has grep, sed, gawk, etc.

Comment: UnxUtils hasn't been maintained for years.  Use GnuWin32 or Cygwin instead.

Comment: gnu on windows (gow) is more complete than GnuWin32: https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki/

Answer (score 4):

An excellent and very fast file search utility, [Agent Ransack](http://mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home), supports regular expression searching.  It's primarily a GUI utility, but a command-line interface is also available.

Answer (score 4):

Update: This wasn't true when the question was originally asked, but now Microsoft lets one [Install the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#install-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux), and Windows will then run grep.  In PowerShell, run:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives this error :   'Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Thanks btw.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791080/select-object-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-pr/53580584#53580584

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the windows reskit there is a utility called "qgrep".  You may have it on your box already.  ;-)  It also comes with the "tail" command, thank god!

Answer (score 2):

the all-in-one busybox contains grep / egrep / sed / awk and MANY more

get it from:

- http://frippery.org/busybox/index.html
- http://frippery.org/files/busybox/?C=M;O=D

Update: no longer available - or some older

- https://github.com/pclouds/busybox-w32

Comment: why do i get downvotes when the questioner asked for third party tools?

Answer (score 2):

You have obviously gotten a lot of different recommendations.
My personal choice for a Free, 3rd Party Utility is:   Agent Ransack
[Agent Ransack Download](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/download)
Despite its somewhat confusing name, it works well and can be used in a variety of ways to find files.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Although not technically grep nor command line, both Microsoft Visual Studio and [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/) have a very good Find in Files feature with full regular expression support. I find myself using them frequently even though I also have the CygWin version of grep available on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my $0.02 to this thread. [dnGREP](http://code.google.com/p/dngrep/) is a great open source grep tool for windows that supports undo, windows explorer integration, search inside PDFs, zips, DOCs and bunch of other stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is only one program for Windows PC which have solid GUI and it is essential util for me. I work as a developer and on every computer I've had, first thing install XFind program. It is created in 1997 and till now version is 1.0 and till now works and it is the best. Frequently I need to search some string in a "*.cs", "*.aspx", "*.sct" (Visual FoxPro form code file) or just "*.*" and XFind scans all files and show me files and another great thing is that you can look where string is in the file. XFind has also some kind of editor. If it binary file it will show you string finded. Try it and use it forever if you are developer like me.

Answer (score 1):

I realize its an old question but I came across this post seeking an answer. And I have found one so adding it here for the collective internet memory

Powershell:  Select-String
Module:
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string

and an informative blog post with advanced examnples: "How to “grep” in PowerShell"
https://antjanus.com/blog/web-development-tutorials/how-to-grep-in-powershell/

A simple example from that blog post:
cat package.json | Select-String -Pattern webpack
ls ./src/components/ | Select-String -Pattern View

C:> cat post.md | Select-String -Pattern "^\w*:"

Answer (score 1):

Use Cygwin...

it has 32 and 64 bits versions
and it works fine from Windows 2000 (*)
 
to Windows 10 or Server 2019

I use Cygwin for a long time... 
 
and recently tryed to substitute with Windows-Linux-Subsystems...

not for long... 
 
I quickly went back to Cygwin again...

much more flexible, controlable and rich...
also less intrusive...

just add \bin to the path... 
and you can use it anyware in Windows/Batch/Powershell...
or in a DOS-Box... or in a Powershell-Box...

Also you can install a ton of great packages
that really work... like nginX or PHP...
I even use the Cygwin PHP package in my IIS...

As a bonus wou can also use it from a bash shell...
(I think this was the original intent ;-))

Answer (score 0):

[Bare Grep](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/) is nice if you want a GUI. [Gnu grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) is good for CLI

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a paid-for product, PowerGREP is my personal favorite.

Answer (score 0):

We have recently used [PowerGREP](http://www.powergrep.com/) for some fairly advanced bulk operations on thousands of files. Including regex searching in content of PDF files, and altering PDF documents in largescale.

Its worth the money if you want to save time from manuel labour. You can try it before you buy i think.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use bare Windows, then in addition to the Powershell option noted above, you can use VBScript, which has decent RegEx support.

MS also has a decent scripting area on Technet with a ton of examples for administrators.

Answer (score 0):

Just try LikeGrep java utility.
It may help you in very many cases. 
As you wish, it can also replace some text, found in files.
It garantees its work on large files (up-to 8 Gb tested)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the gnuwin32 project has a Windows CLI version of grep.

If you want something with a graphical interface, I would recommend the (open-source) tool [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I've used them, but Borland (Embarcadero now) included a command line grep with their C/C++ compiler.  For some time, they have made available their 5.5 version as a [free download](https://downloads.embarcadero.com/item/24778) after registering.

Answer (score 0):

There's a commercial grep utility available from [Oak Road Systems](http://www.oakroadsystems.com/sharware/grep.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **[PowerGrep](http://www.powergrep.com)**

I had to do an e-discovery project several years ago. I found that `fisdstr` had some limitations, most especially **fisdstr would eventually fail**

the script had to search across thousands of files using a couple of dozen search terms/phrases.

**Cygwin's grep worked much better**, it didn't choke often, but ultimately I went to PowerGrep because the graphical interface made it much easier to tell when and where it crashed, and also it was really easy to edit in all the conditionals and output that I wanted.  Ultimately **PowerGrep was the most reliable** of the three.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's a bit old topic but, here is another thing you can do. I work on a developer VM with no internet access and quite limited free disk space, so I made use of the java installed on it.

Compile small java program that prints regex matches to the console. Put the jar somewhere on your system, create a batch to execute it and add the folder to your PATH variable:

**JGrep.java:**

```
package com.jgrep;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JGrep {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        int printGroup = -1;
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Invalid arguments. Usage:");
            System.out.println("jgrep [...-MODIFIERS] [PATTERN] [FILENAME]");
            System.out.println("Available modifiers:");
            System.out.println(" -printGroup            - will print the given group only instead of the whole match. Eg: -printGroup=1");
            System.out.println("Current arguments:");
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("args[" + i + "]=" + args[i]);
            }
            return;
        }
        Pattern pattern = null;
        String filename = args[args.length - 1];
        String patternArg = args[args.length - 2];        
        pattern = Pattern.compile(patternArg);

        int argCount = 2;
        while (args.length - argCount - 1 >= 0) {
            String arg = args[args.length - argCount - 1];
            argCount++;
            if (arg.startsWith("-printGroup=")) {
                printGroup = Integer.parseInt(arg.substring("-printGroup=".length()));
            }
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sb.toString());
        int matchesCount = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            if (printGroup > 0) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(printGroup));
            } else {
                System.out.println(matcher.group());
            }
            matchesCount++;
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("File: " + filename);
        System.out.println("Pattern: " + pattern.pattern());
        System.out.println("PrintGroup: " + printGroup);
        System.out.println("Matches: " + matchesCount);
    }
}
```

**c:\jgrep\jgrep.bat** (together with jgrep.jar):

```
@echo off
java -cp c:\jgrep\jgrep.jar com.jgrep.JGrep %*
```

and add *c:\jgrep* in the end of the PATH environment variable.

Now simply call `jgrep "expression" file.txt` from anywhere.

I needed to print some specific groups from my expression so I added a modifier and call it like `jgrep -printGroup=1 "expression" file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

May be [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/)? It supports regexps and has a console util too.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR: [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

Since 2009, a lot happened. Rust delivered many CLI utilities, among them [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep). It is advertised as a *recursively searches directories for a regex pattern*, supports **Windows**, MacOSX and Linux.

It is **fast**. [Look at this performance comparison with similar tools](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/). It also has many explanations on the design of the tool. Quite informative and geeky. =)

Supports a wide range of features that the POSIX grep tools support. [Look at the comparison by ack author here](https://beyondgrep.com/feature-comparison/).

If you have Scoop, you can install it with `scoop install ripgrep`. Else head over to the [installation section of the doc](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep#installation).