# How to show lines of a text file that contain a certain keyword - CMD

Tags: batch-file, command-line, types, cmd

I need some way to show the lines of text file that contain a certain keyword.
It's usually `TYPE path:\to\file` but I want it to show all lines that contain a keyword of choice.

Regard ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `find "keyword" path:\to\file`

Answer (score 2):

`find "keyword" path:\to\file` or `findstr /c:"keyword" path:\to\file` are  options.
If you want to clear the `---------- FileName` part of the output you can use

`type path:\to\file | find "keyword"`
or
`type path:\to\file | findstr /c:"keyword"`

to show line numbers use `/n`

`type path:\to\file | find /n "keyword"`

or

`type path:\to\file | findstr /n /c:"keyword"`

**EDIT**

foxidrive reminded another way (see the comment):

`find "keyword" < "path:\to\file"`

Comment: `find "keyword" < "path:\to\file"` is another option.

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX, grep does this.

In Windows, you can use [Powershell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416241/is-there-a-pattern-matching-utility-like-grep-in-windows) for a grep equivalent.