# Magento 2 Theme hardcoded google maps api url's

Tags: php, templates, magento, magento2, magento2.1

I am configuring a magento 2.1.7 deployment, using IIS with php.

I am running a theme from TemplateMonster ([Theme](https://www.templatemonster.com/magento-themes/mountainlife-climber-s-gear-magento-2-theme-magento-theme-63398.html))

I have configured my store to run via SSL, but I get a mixed content warning, as there are some JS scripts that are trying to load a google maps api reference over http. This happens on all the pages of the store. The pages are created dynamically, hence I can't trace where the code is injected from.

For the life of me, I cannot locate where this is implemented in the template or magento source. I have scoured through all the content blocks and pages, and I just can't find it. My magento theming skills are 0, so I have no clue where a theme developer would add code that is mixed into every rendered page.

My warning:

```
Mixed Content: The page at '***.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=initialize'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

The source is reported as page that does not exist (dynamically generated)

This is the code block that is causing my issues, I just can't find it!

```
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do a grep / search on all theme files for googleapis for locating the place where theme are loading it. If you cannot find it, then the theme aren't the problem (maybe a database value?).

Comment: Ahh, I neglected to mention, that I am on IIS with PHP configured. Unfortunately no grep. I did try a windows search (include file contents), but we all know how well that works...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416241/is-there-a-pattern-matching-utility-like-grep-in-windows <-- Check this question for some tools grep-equivalent on Windows.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick... I found the culprit. I am going to add the solution below for reference. Thanks a stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @sakura Kinomoto 's suggestion above, I used the tool `findstr` to locate the file containing the text I was looking for.

The file in question was: 
`wwwroot\app\code\TemplateMonster\GoogleMap\view\frontend\templates\init.phtml`