# How can I find a specific word in a file using command line?

Tags: command-line, command-prompt

Using git bash I want to search for a file and then find a specific word in this file. How can I do that?

Comment: For finding a file - https://superuser.com/a/401499

Comment: For searching a word in the file - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1416247/4688321

Comment: `grep -R` is usefull. [`grep --help`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).