# Azure Emulator Won't Launch When Using Node.js + Socket.io

Tags: node.js, azure, emulation, socket.io

I'm using the Windows Azure SDK for Node.js and run into an extremely odd roadblock.

I can test  Azure Node.js apps locally using the Windows Azure Emulator fine, *until* I install Socket.io. Then the emulator *refuses* to start, spitting out:

```
Creating local package...
Starting Emulator...
Start-AzureEmulator : An unexpected failure occurred.  Details:
The compute emulator had a error: Can't locate service model..
At line:1 char:20
+ Start-AzureEmulator <<<<  -Launch
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzureEmulator], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AzureDeploymentCmdlets.Cmdlet.StartAzureEmulatorCommand
```

Odd thing is, I can deploy the same code/project to Azure, and it runs fine. Only the emulator refuses to work.

What is also odd is that I can't replicate this on a different computer. It seems to only be an issue on my main work box. I've tried `npm cache clear` to get a fresh install of Socket.io. I've uninstalled and re-installed the Azure SDK, Azure Emulators, and Azure Node.js tools. Nothing has fixed the issue.

Any ideas? It is getting mighty frustrating to only be able to test after a 10-15 minute deploy to the cloud.

**UPDATE:**
I should clarify that this scenario is happening with only a worker role (no web roles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to have been fixed with the release of the Windows Azure SDK for Node.js - August 2012 (Version: 0.6.2). This can be installed via Web Platform Installer 4.0.

Answer (score 3):

On a hunch (because I think I may have had a similar error elsewhere in the past),  I shortened the name of my project directory which resolved the issue.

I've a feeling it may be to do with the length of the path to the project files in the filesystem. I know TFS has similar issues. I usually try to keep all my projects in C:\Dev and not have too many nested directories or long project names.

There may be other reasons for seeing this error, but this resolved the issue in my case.

Comment: I've been following the cloud-services-nodejs-chat-app-socketio Azure tutorial, had this problem and moving to a shorter directory path also worked for me. My original path had no spaces and was about 25 characters longer (including \ separators). Bugs like this shouldn't happen any more... who is in charge of this? :)

Comment: I've since discovered that this is a limitation in windows, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Express framework in a web role? I ran into a permissions problem (which this may well be another symptom of) with the basic sample of using the Express framework with node.js in a web role in the emulator.

This is caused by a packaging bug. The workaround is to delete the server.js.logs directory from the web role. You can then turn off IISNode logging using the [loggingEnabled](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-nodejs-applications-in-iis-on.html) parameter.

Comment: This may work for web roles and Express, but not worker roles and socket.io, which is what I'm trying to run in the Azure Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

We have a fix on the way for this in our next SDK update which will be shortly.

Comment: So I'm not out of my mind. That's nice to know. Would there happen to be any workarounds right now?

Comment: Hey Glenn, I just grabbed the latest release of tools (from the big Azure update last week) and I'm still having the same issue. Make a new project: `New-AzureServiceProject test`, `Add-AzureNodeWorkerRole`, navigate into WorkerRole1, `npm install socket.io`, `Start-AzureEmulator -Launch`, and it spits out the same error from the question. Do you know if there is any planned fix for this?

Comment: Try moving your app folder to a shorter path as suggested by bitsprint. Worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

"Would there happen to be any workarounds right now?"

I realise I have minimal reputation on StackOverflow but my earlier post did contain the phrase "The workaround." (And thanks to Glenn and his team for getting me there, on another forum.)

Comment: Sorry, but no. I'm not even using a web role - I'm using only a worker role, since IIS 7 doesn't play nice with web sockets. So I have no Web.config files, nor a server.js.logs. So your workaround won't work for me, thus why I didn't mark it as an answer.

This secondary answer you posted is not an answer at all. Answers should not be used as comments or complaints.