# Android Studio - Unable to open PNG file

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I'm trying to integrate Facebook into my app, but while running it in Android Studio, I get this:

> Gradle: Execution failed for task ':AplikaceBeta1.0.1:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.2.2\aapt.exe s -i C:\Users\David\Desktop\facebook-android-sdk-3.5\facebook-android-sdk-3.5\samples\AplikaceBeta1.0.1Project\AplikaceBeta1.0.1\build\exploded-bundles\AplikaceBeta101ProjectLibrariesFacebookUnspecified.aar\res\drawable\com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square.png -o C:\Users\David\Desktop\facebook-android-sdk-3.5\facebook-android-sdk-3.5\samples\AplikaceBeta1.0.1Project\AplikaceBeta1.0.1\build\res\all\debug\drawable\com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square.png
>   Error Code:
>       42
>   Output:
>       C:\Users\David\Desktop\facebook-android-sdk-3.5\facebook-android-sdk-3.5\samples\AplikaceBeta1.0.1Project\AplikaceBeta1.0.1\build\exploded-bundles\AplikaceBeta101ProjectLibrariesFacebookUnspecified.aar\res\drawable\com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file

Unable to open PNG file... what?!

Code is totally the same as in "[Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android (Android Studio)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android-using-android-studio/3.0/)" guide. It's really simple, this is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.aplikacebeta101;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)             {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                            welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

Any ideas? I know, Android Studio is still EAP, but I think this is not caused by Android Studio.

Comment: This error is connected with Gradle not Android Studio. I had it when I wanted to run a project on Windows copied from Mac. I really don't know why but when I have copied the same project from Windows to Windows, everything was OK...

Comment: this may be releated to too long paths... but Im not sure

Comment: In the Windows Shell, if you want to use paths longer than 260 characters, you have to prepend them with \\?\. This looks like something we could pretty easily fix by just changing the build rules slightly. I'll mention it to the Android Studio team.

Answer (score 59):

Are you using Windows? This error could happen if the generated build file path exceeds the Windows (*not NTFS*) max path length of **260** characters. Make sure your project path is not too long, use short names as well. [More info from MS:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> **Maximum Path Length Limitation**
>   In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string" where "" represents the invisible terminating null character for the current system codepage. (The characters < > are used here for visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)

Also see [discussion why the limitation Windows exists.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows)

Comment: awsme thanks a lot!! I have wasted my long time to debug this!! thanks a lot !!!! works for me

Comment: @NiravShah what you did too resolve this path issue so that it worked??

Comment: @mukeshpatel just move your workspace to e.g. root folder C:\yourapp

Comment: @mukeshpatel : Correct. Move your project to the nearest root folder like C:\\ , D:\\ etc

Answer (score 0):

As @for3st said, it's a path length problem in windows.
Try mapping a virtual driving and shorten path using this : http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/visual-subst.html