# CreateProcess error=206, The filename, or extension is too long

Tags: android, android-studio

```
CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long - Android Studio
```

What does this error mean and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Android-Studio in committing projects and Tortoise SVN, seems like tortoise-svn does the job unlike android-studio's plugin which is SVN. I dont really understand why, but Tortoise-svn is working so I think this could be an answer.

Make long story short: The temporary-fix is using Tortoise Svn rather than using Android-Studio's SVN.

Comment: I got the same error, but I'm not using SVN at all (all GIT), so it shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: That`s not related to SVN check this question and see first answer it solve problems of many developers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981137/android-studio-3-1-1-createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-l/49981764

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a max path length of 260 characters. See max path length of 260 characters. See [Android Studio - Unable to open PNG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556280/android-studio-unable-to-open-png-file)

Comment: i dont quite get the solution. but thanks to your answer though. the thing im troubled is that i tried tortoise svn. but it works and in android-studio doesnt.

Comment: Could be a bug with android studio that tortise svn fixed. Submit it to the android studio bug report site!

Answer (score 0):

According to another thread the "svn cmd absolute path" works, but the relative one "cd /your/project/path;svn cmd yourproject" doesn´t (It´s a Windows File System "Problem")

Android Studio seem to work with relative paths, Tortoise with absolute. The error message also says

> cannot run program ( IN directory .../.../yourproject)

Which confirms this assumption.

Hopefully they will change it in future!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and installing Tortoise SVN didn't solve it. I proceeded to commit individual directories in my project step by step, trying to find the file/directory that was causing the problem. My surprise was when I finished all commits and no error had arised.

So the solution for my problem was to commit all my files/directories step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is a bit old but here is a  a work around for googlers ,

Android Studio gives you the exact address of the folder which can not be committed:

```
Error:Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "c:\blah-blah"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
```

Unless AS or Microsoft does something for supporting file names longer than the current limitation, here is a couple of workarounds to pass this :

1- to commit the given folder `c:\blah-blah` using another svn client `eg. TortoiseSVN`

2- to move your project folder closer to the root of the drive, for example if your project is in `d:\Development\Android Studio\sources\project x\Version 3\...` try to move it closer to the root, by removing and/or renaming in between folders like: `d:\dev\as\src\x\v3\...` or `d:\x\v3\...`

3- I read somewhere that creating a virtual drive in windows from the last folder would work too, for example, create a `z:\` and assign it to `d:\Development\Android Studio\sources\project x\Version 3\` but I read somewhere else that this might not work cause the AS svn client work with absolute path of files, any way I made the job done with options 1 and 2 and never got to try the third option

Answer (score 0):

The error is often produced when too many files are commited at once and the command line client is used; as the files are delivered to the client in one line, the line becomes too long (svn commit file1 file2 ...). See also [SVN commit fails when committing lots of files in one commit (resulting svn command length exceed the limit)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122217). My solution to this problem was to uncheck "Use command line client" in the settings under "Version Control - Subversion".

Comment: Thats not related to SVN because of that i face this issue even i don`t user SVN, check this link and see first answer you have better idea of why you face this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981137/android-studio-3-1-1-createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-l/49981764