# Android Studio 3.1.1 CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, createprocess

I am getting the below exception when building the app from Android Studio
It says

> CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long at

I had tried enabling longer paths in Windows regedit, but still facing the issue. Please help!

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe''

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe''
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe''
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarTransform.transform(DesugarTransform.java:292)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe''
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:222)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:202)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:342)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.run(BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.java:35)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'C:\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe'
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" (in directory "D:\CodeRepository\Android\iamhere-android-app\app"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 11 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

BUILD FAILED in 7m 38s
107 actionable tasks: 11 executed, 96 up-to-date

Comment: How does your code look like?

Comment: It is an Android project with Java and Kotlin code. But, my colleagues using the same code are not facing the issue

Comment: Try to reduce the level of directory structure. Bring your project as close as possible to  your root directory

Comment: Thanks Sagar & pinegulf

Comment: did you figure out which dependency was causing this?

Comment: how did you solve this problem?(Have the same one) placed the project closer to your root directory? it not works for me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess you are the windows user, there is a file path limit of 8191 in Windows XP and above.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473/en-us

The simplest way this shorten the file path, like change the project folder into D:\, and refact your project path, and always use ASCII chars for the folder name. UTF-8 chars use 2-3 bytes.
or move useless dependency.
or change to MAC platform. ;)

The reason is at the compile step, there is a command like javac xxxx, combine all dependences's path in one line.

Comment: Thanks xingjiu, you saved my day

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue as well

Comment: Yup, this is the only way I'm aware of. If you don't want to move all your stuff, you still can use **virtual drive pointing to your original folder** ! See this [blog entry](https://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/mount-folder-as-drive-windows) for detailed explainations !

Comment: This is incorrect: Gradle executes its commands using [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), so the maximum command size is **32,768**.

Comment: Virtual drive works for me. Create a batch file; subst Z: "D:\Projects\Your Project\...."

Comment: This workaround really works. I can't believe how naive the developers of gradle are.

Comment: i moved my project into a d: path and i stil got the same error?

Comment: path change will not work for me i have many files still getting error  Any other solution ?

Comment: I had the same error because there was another instance of OpenJDK which was using some cache resource. Killing the other instances helped.

Answer (score 8):

For me this worked.

1. Go to Build -> Clean.
2. File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart

Or

It might be due to network issue. Please check connectivity.

Comment: yeah, it's worked after Invalidate Cache and Restart

Comment: Bad solution, So I have to do this every time i build???

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **intellij idea** you can shorten command line by doing the following:

1. go to Run/Debug Configuration
2. pick **classpath file** in **Shorten command line** drop box. Example below.

[image: Shorten comman line example]

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this recently as well.
This worked for me:

1. subst X: C:\Users$PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT to create a virtual mount
2. Open `cmd`

   - Type `gpedit.msc`
   - `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem`
   - enable Win32 long paths
   - reboot

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked by following steps:

1. Build -> Clean Project.
2. File -> Invalidate caches & Restart.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29762371)

Answer (score 0):

In my case all I had to do was move the project folder from it's original location to the desktop.
The new project location became - `C:\Users\YourPCName\Desktop\YourProjectName`

Comment: This looks like a comment than an answer