# Android Studio crash (aapt.exe returns 42) when I put PNG file in drawable folder

Tags: android, android-studio

After yesterday's update it won't build or run project with these 2 PNG images as background image. As soon as I delete these images everything works fine again (I put images in drawable folder).

```
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
C:\Users\Daedlues\Desktop\Android-Studio-Projects\AndroidInterView\app\src\main\res\drawable\middle.png
Error:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Daedlues\Desktop\Work\SDK\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\Daedlues\Desktop\Android-Studio-Projects\AndroidInterView\app\src\main\res\drawable\middle.png: Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Daedlues\Desktop\Work\SDK\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 13):

This can also happen if you exceed the Windows max path length.

[Android Studio - Unable to open PNG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556280/android-studio-unable-to-open-png-file)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helps me too :-)

Comment: Very clever, this was my problem too. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I was scratching my head for this issue until now :)

Answer (score 4):

If 'yesterdays update' refers to Android 5.1 (API 22) then try using the latest version of the build tools. Adjust your build.gradle to use `buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"`

Comment: Solved it for me, thanks. Why does Google keep breaking stuff?

Comment: This is not help! The actual problem is the limitation of file length (include path) as Herrbert74 answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it turned out that the "png" image was really a "psd" image that simply had the wrong extension. I had to convert it to a "png" and then the error went away.

Comment: Thanks! In my case it was jpeg with ".png" extension!

Answer (score 0):

***This can happen when gradle fails to process resources.***

In my case it happened to be an invalid image file in the drawable folder, that's why my XML layouts that Android Studio didn't pick up on ...
for that solution i am prefer both ways

**1>** **check your extension & convert them .png into .jpeg**

**2> if that useless then delete from drawable**

Answer (score 0):

Check  the image middle.png.
if it is an image with format jpg or jpeg,that is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and doing a **./gradle clean build** solved it !

Answer (score 0):

We got this error message too. For some reason, our files were named `foo.9.png` - and the extra dot tripped up the build. So, check if you have any superfluous dots in the file name too.