# Rebuilding Error

Tags: java, android, debugging, sdk, building

C:\Users\I\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\exchange.png
Error:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\I\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\exchange.png: Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42

This question isn't answered with an accepted answer on stackoverflow
My R.java doesn't work to. Does anyone know how to solve these problems.
build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023830/android-studio-crash-aapt-exe-returns-42-when-i-put-png-file-in-drawable-folde

Comment: This is an problem and this is no duplicate my R.java doesn't work to!

Comment: looks same to me. Problem on png and exit code 42. Did you try the answer from the other question?

Comment: Yes but it didn't work:

Comment: @Anoniem - was your error solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a drawable plugin or check your images op good sizes!
Make drawable maps because mipmap is only for icons.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the PNG file where you get the error is really a PNG file. I had the same problem and I realized it was a JPG.

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml code. Make sure you have no capitalized naming of ids. and also check your xml file names to ensure none of them have capitalized naming or invalid characters such as numbers.

2. You can also try replacing your "exchange.png" file in main\res\mipmap-hdpi\exchange.png with another file to see if it works, since your logcat is pointing to that file.

Comment: If I replace/delete that file then there is a next error in one of the other png files. I have added some more info

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing a **./gradlew clean build** on the terminal. After that, type **./gradlew --refresh-dependencies** and you should be good to go!