# "non-zero exit value 42"

Tags: java, android-studio

I am having an issue with adding custom images to my app.  When I do,I get gradle errors.  I searched on here and seen the solution to add:

```
android: {
   useNewCruncher false
}
```

But that didn't help.  I am still getting the "non-zero exit value 42 error".  Here is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
aaptOptions {
    useNewCruncher false
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.androidbootcamp.techgadgets"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}
```

Here are most of the gradle errors

> Error:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/SlyInstinct/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 42
>
> :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   /Users/SlyInstinct/Documents/AppProjects/AndroidStudioProjects/TechGadgets/app/src/main/res/drawable/butler.png: Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/SlyInstinct/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 42
>   Here is the main activity Java

```
package net.androidbootcamp.techgadgets;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String [] tech ={"Self Driving Car", "Bionic Butler", "Jetpack", "Robot Dogs", "Virtual Reality"};
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tech));

}
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/selfdrivingcar/")));
            break;
        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence")));
            break;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.martinjetpack.com/")));
            break;
        case 3:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.bostondynamics.com/robot_bigdog.html")));
            break;
        case 4:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.oculus.com/en-us/")));
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the logcat

```
03-06 19:59:16.970 1296-1296/? E/LocationManagerService: no geocoder provider found
03-06 19:59:16.970 1296-1296/? E/FlpHardwareProvider: Error hw_get_module 'flp': -2
03-06 19:59:16.970 1296-1296/? E/LocationManagerService: FLP HAL not supported
03-06 19:59:16.970 1296-1296/? W/ServiceWatcher: com.google.android.location not found
03-06 19:59:16.970 1296-1296/? E/LocationManagerService: Unable to bind FLP Geofence proxy.
03-06 19:59:16.970 1296-1296/? E/ActivityRecognitionHardware: Error hw_get_module: -2
03-06 19:59:16.970 1296-1296/? E/LocationManagerService: Hardware Activity-Recognition not supported.
03-06 19:59:16.970 1296-1313/? E/GpsLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
03-06 19:59:16.990 1296-1296/? I/CommonTimeManagementService: No common time service detected on this platform.  Common time services will be unavailable.
03-06 19:59:16.990 1296-1296/? I/MmsServiceBroker: Connecting to MmsService
03-06 19:59:16.990 1296-1296/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.bindService:1750 com.android.server.MmsServiceBroker.tryConnecting:134 com.android.server.MmsServiceBroker.systemRunning:121 com.android.server.SystemServer$2.run:1182 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.systemReady:11326 
03-06 19:59:16.990 1296-1331/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000030
03-06 19:59:17.000 1419-1419/? E/SQLiteLog: (283) recovered 30 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db-wal
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023830/android-studio-crash-aapt-exe-returns-42-when-i-put-png-file-in-drawable-folde

Comment: Turns out the images provided by the instructor were corrupted.  I re-saved them in a photo editing app and it resolved the problem.