# Android Studio Gradle Task Failed

Tags: android

Hello need to ask how can fix this problem on Android Stuudio show this 2 Errors

```
Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
Error while executing '....\Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe' 
with arguments {singleCrunch -i 
....\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.2.0\res\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png -o
....\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png}
```

Second Error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.> 
Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
Error while executing '....\Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe' 
with arguments {singleCrunch -i 
....\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.2.0\res\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png -o 
....\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png}
```

Comment: You are using SDK 21 to compile, but using SDK 22 support library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio crash (aapt.exe returns 42) when I put PNG file in drawable folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023830/android-studio-crash-aapt-exe-returns-42-when-i-put-png-file-in-drawable-folde)

Comment: @GAVD Where is the 42 error code?

Comment: I think you have put image in `drawable-ldrtl-hdpi` which is incorrect.