# Android Studio 1.2 "Can't open PNG"... but I'm not referencing any images

Tags: android-studio

I get this error:

`D:\production\Pong\Devel2010\Src\UnityGames\BhvrDemo\AndroidPushNotification\AndroidPluginProject\bhvrpushnotification\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.0.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file`

`:bhvrpushnotification:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources FAILED`

The plugin used to compile, I don't know what's changed. It's a Unity push notification plugin, and has no activity or interface.

How can I find out where this png is being referenced from in the build?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio - Unable to open PNG file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556280/android-studio-unable-to-open-png-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory path might be too long - try shortening it. Also see

[Android Studio - Unable to open PNG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556280/android-studio-unable-to-open-png-file)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is probably the problem... but why is an image referenced in my project?