# Android studio Gradle build finished with 1 error(s)

Tags: android

I copied an Android project from a mac computer to a PC with a where i recently installed Android studio with a new SDK version. I imported the project using my pc and i got the following error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Crunching Cruncher common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark.9.png failed, see logs

I failed to solve this issue, Please help
Thanks

Comment: "my project directory"\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\7.8.0\res\drawable-mdpi\common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556280/android-studio-unable-to-open-png-file

Answer (score 0):

Replace `common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark.9.png` with

```
common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark9.png
```

Comment: Hello. Every time i run the project again it rename the png files to its original names, even if i delete those files they come back again

Comment: BTW, on my other mac computer it is runing perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, all i need to do is shorten the path name of the project.