# Png image Error

Tags: android, png

I am new in android programming.I am using Android Studio.I have created a project but when i am going run the project It create's two Error :

```
Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42
```

&

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > C:\Users\User\Downloads\SingleGridView\app\src\main\res\drawable\channel9.png:
> >     Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 42

How can i solve it? I am using windows 7..

Code here >

```
int[] pprImg = { R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.channel9

    } ;
```

Comment: have you placed the png file on the res/drawable or you addressing the full path to the file?

Comment: share the code where you are referencing this drawable `channel9.png`. Are u referencing it as `R.drawable.channel9` or some other way. If another way, reference it using the id in R.

Comment: Now see the java code .. and say what should i do now ? @virus & @ Itzik samara ..

Comment: what is the location of the .png file you are using.?

Comment: app>src>main>res>drawable>channel9.png/otherimg  @Ragu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the Win 7, then check the following points and make it work

**Check 1 :** This is because generated build file path exceeds 260 characters which windows will not support. Make sure your project path is not too long. Refer [From Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)  , [From Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556280/android-studio-unable-to-open-png-file)

**Check 2 :** Make sure the ".png" file you are using is actually a PNG file, if not convert it to ".png" file. Because sometimes the actual file format may be ".jpg" or ".psd" and by mistake you renamed it as .png . Double check the extension of the png file you used.

**Check 3 :** Try renaming your file.

**Check 4 :** Your image named "channel9.png" , try to rename this image to something like "channel_nine.png", because it ends with "9.png" which may be misunderstood as 9 patch image.  **Normal PNG File : *.png , 9-Patch File : *.9.png**

**Check 5 :** Adjust your build.gradle to use buildToolsVersion "22.0.0" or "22.0.1"

**Check 6 :** If you do Check 5 - Try to change all your dependencies to point 22.0.x

**Check 7 :** Clean your Project.

**Check 8 :** Rebuild your Project.

Hope this helps you in solving the error.