# Android Studio: “Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'” if project is created on drive C:

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, google-play-services

I added Google Play services as a dependency in my current project.
If I save the project on the C: drive,
I get the following error while syncing up the project:

```
Error: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
       > Error: Failed to run command:
       C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2\aapt.exe s -i C:\Users\ashokp\Desktop\Studio\AndroidV2SDK_AndroidStudioFormat\Google Play
       Services\SampleApplication\AndroidV2SDKSampleApp_GooglePlayServices\app\build\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\4.3.23\res\drawable-hdpi\common_signin_btn_text_focus_light.9.png -o
       C:\Users\ashokp\Desktop\Studio\AndroidV2SDK_AndroidStudioFormat\Google Play
       Services\SampleApplication\AndroidV2SDKSampleApp_GooglePlayServices\app\build\res\all\debug\drawable-hdpi\common_signin_btn_text_focus_light.9.png
       Error Code:
       42
```

This only happens if the project is saved on the C: drive.
If I save it to some other drive, it works perfectly.

Does anyone else face this issue?
What causes this?
How can I fix/circumvent this?

[image]

Comment: Can you try copying Google Play Services to another location so the path is shorter? Windows has some restrictions on path length.

Comment: How are you adding play services? As a gradle dependency?

Comment: @Eugene I feel the same.May be this issue is occurring because of path length restriction.

Comment: @athor Yes sir I am adding it as a gradle dependency.                              compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'

Comment: This solution here worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/1880494/1427791

Comment: I got this same error on a Mac when I upgraded my gradle (as the compiler suggested).  What's the similarity?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is caused by the path length restriction.
I think it's 256 characters maximum.

Relocate your project and the build will succeed.

Comment: It wors for me. On Windows, I moved the project from Documents to C:/ and worked.

Comment: Also, It can be duplicate resources error, for example of if you put two icons (same file name but different file type) into the drawable folder. It will cause this error.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. Try to go to Build - Rebuild project. I didn't get that problem again and my app successfully started.

Comment: Technically it does provide an answer to the question. Just not the answer you think the question deserves. If someone had a successful solution, which clearly worked for more than one person in this specific case, then it is a legitimate answer.

Answer (score 9):

For developers who live in Iran, Just rebuild while offline. You're done! (it's related to sanctions!)

Comment: using VPN help me too!

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar problem with `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources`. And at last I found the reason is the pictures resource error which use the incorrect ".9.png".

Comment: i tried refractoring the ".9.png" but i still encounter the problem

Answer (score 3):

add this in module's build.gradle.

```
android{
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
}
```

Comment: what is module's build.gradle ? is to app/build.gradle or root build.gradle ?

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio 1.4 with `buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'` the [approach of fvasquezc23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25209204/2415161) worked for me with a restart and cache invalidation.

So, after you change the location of your project folder – copy/paste the folder onto disk D: (or somewhere else with no big ‘folder in folder’ structure), just

- go to “File” -> “Invalidate Caches/Restart” (below “Synchronize”)
- select first option “Invalidate and Restart”

Answer (score 2):

In drawable assets there was an image format which was an unsupported image. When i removed the image every thing started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case

1. I Followed [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680677/5705721)
2. Changed the location of project.
3. Tried another android device [Build and success install]
4. Tried on my android device [Build and success install * Uninstall any previous version of same app on device]

**Edit-**
Again it happend

I had this error message and lot of others like

`x-version is deprecated and use y-version instead and it'll be removed in 2019`

and all of my project started giving same error messages suddenly.

Android studio was giving warnings about my antivirus program. I tried configuring it but didn't work.

Finally **I uninstalled QuickHeal antivirus from my system** and all is well now

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue after i updated to Android-Studio 3.6 the only way that worked for me was downgrading project build.gradle setting by changing

from

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I created a folder `audio` in `res` directory. That caused the problem! Deleting the folder fixed it. Hope it might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error.

In the end, the problem was that I used an image in res/drawable that I copied in there and saved it as .png although the original file was .jpg .

I deleted the file (there's a warning message if there are still usages for the item in your code, but you can ignore it) and pasted it in with the original .jpg ending.

After a cleanup and gradle syncronization the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Remove any capital letters or other not allowed symbols in resource file name.

Example: activity_parkingList --> activity_parking_list

Answer (score 1):

Update your gradle build tools in project level gradle , and it will show you the exact resource that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Dont make name with capital letters . Always use lowercase  for naming . This will work fine .
like companyLogo.png will raise error but company_logo.png will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ionic 
in config.xml update widget tag with "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

```html
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">


<widget/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the right repository in Project build.gradle solved the issue.
In my case Google Maven Repository was needed and was added as below in the build.gradle

```
repositories {
google()
}
```

refer to this link for declaring repositories:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on PC of a company that uses a proxy you must turn on your VPN

Answer (score 1):

when we add some new thing in out project, in that case some times resources might get duplicate that time it will give the error while run the app, in my case also get same issue I had face, while I had added the kotlin activity in java project, in it gives me error

**Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
...\themes.xml: Error: Duplicate resources**

so in this case please check the local history and remove the duplicate resources from res folder, so simply revert that changes

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that I had defined some color in colors.xml twice and after commenting one of them out, it solved the issue. and now i'm **furious**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error and by process of elimination I discovered the problem to be a single apostrophe (') in a string resource. (Specifically, a  string array item.) Replacing the apostrophe with the `&#39;` entity didn't work either. Escaping it with `\'` however, did work and my project built. I discovered the proper escape code through Android Studio's string resource editor. The build error message was completely unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

This caused the problem for me: I put an ' character on my "strings.xml" file and it crashed everything.

After deleting that ' character it works...

Answer (score 1):

You have "  '  "  symbol in your strings  or arrays somewhere  ... erase it !!!

I have LET'S DOI IT ,   after erasing " ' "  and LET'S  was LETS , problem disapered

Comment: This is exactly the same basic point as https://stackoverflow.com/a/72812927/7733418 You do not even explain relevantly differently, let alone more helpfully. This post does hence contribute nothing new to the problem solving here. Please delete it. As a minor side issue, your future posts might benefit from the info provided here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the project worked for me, Build > clean project.

Comment: If you know why is it working for you after `Clean Project`, Please add more details and causes ;).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was caused by having a button with an angle bracket inside `android:text` field:

```
<Button
   ...
   android:text="<-"
/>
```

Changing it to `android:text="back"` fixed everything.

While having "<-" as a hardcoded text on a button isn't the best practice, it's a shame people have to spend so much time on finding solutions to these kind of issues without getting any informative hints from gradle on what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue while working on a Flutter Application. I solved it by going to Tools > Flutter > Flutter Clean.

Answer (score 0):

I my case, I had duplicated properties in the xml file. The  'android:layout_height' was in my layout tag and also in one of his child.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check if all the files in the values folder are correct. In my case it was the strings.xml where I forgot to escape single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was due to character in string.xml file.

from

```
<string name="machine_coords">MACHINE\nCOORD'S</string>
```

to

```
<string name="machine_coords">MACHINE\nCOORD"'"S</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with the recent change in color XML i failed to insert '#' into the XML file. Please check ur recent changes that can be a cause for concern for this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had rebased on master branch that had a new module addition.
and i had "offline mode" ON for gradle. turned it on and rebuilt the project.
it worked for me.

happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning you project by running:

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew && cd ..
```

then run:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

or

```
npx expo run:android
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Relocate the project in an outer directory.

For example from `C:/Users/x/desktop/AndroidProject` to `C:/projects/AndroidProject`.

Answer (score -1):

Add this two lines to your **build.gradle(app)**

```
aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
```

Comment: where should want to add, i want the exact location?