# Android Studio can't find color reference within the same resource file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

Here's the content of my resource file *\res\values\colors.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="themeGray">#ff8A9199</color>
    <color name="themeLightGray">#ffeaeaea</color>
    <color name="themeDarkGray">#ff3f434b</color>
    <color name="themeRed">#ffCC292B</color>
    <color name="themeBlue">#ff002E63</color>
    <color name="themeWhite">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="buttonNormal">@color/themeGray</color>
    <color name="buttonPressed">@color/themeBlue</color>
</resources>
```

The two values

```
@color/themeGray
@color/themeBlue
```

are red colored **Cannot resolve symbol '@color/themeGray'**

**EDIT**

This what I see in the Message windows:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

Comment: put colors in main project, if you put colors in lower project -> that main won't see it - beacuse is on higher level

Comment: color resource file is actually in the main project

Comment: it looks good. Have you checked for a bug of the IDE ?

Comment: Clean your project once and Rebuilt it, it should work. Hvae you tried syncing it with gradle ?

Comment: No clean/rebuild action works for me

Comment: found a (non) solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359572/android-studio-execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-if-project  I relocated the project and now everything works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying with project clean/compile and File>Invalidate Caches / Restart... with no success, I solved the problem relocating the project to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

to

```
xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

lets see what happens

Answer (score -3):

That also depends on where your are trying to access the resource files. some fields only take rgb format for colors.

Comment: I think It's an issue related to resource compilation, I found that relocating the project resolve the problem.

Comment: files in android dosent affect Color class even if takes rgb format of colors