# Error after trying to change color in color.xml

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm trying to learn Android, now I'm trying to change color in my android project. Here is what I do,

I change my color.xml to:

```
<resources>
    <color name="primaryColor">#d81b60</color>
    <color name="primaryLightColor">#ff5c8d</color>
    <color name="primaryDarkColor">#a00037</color>
    <color name="primaryTextColor">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

and my style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="primaryColor">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="primaryLightColor">@color/primaryLightColor</item>
    <item name="primaryDarkColor">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="primaryTextColor">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
</style>
```

But when I try to run I get this error(s):

[image]

So, how can I fix it?

I already try this:

1. [Android Studio does not find color style resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716023/android-studio-does-not-find-color-style-resource)
2. [Android Studio can't find color reference within the same resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422286/android-studio-cant-find-color-reference-within-the-same-resource-file)

Comment: try using `android:color/primaryColor`

Comment: did you add your appcompat library in dependencies in gradle file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

in style these tags are used to specify the colorPrimary accent and primaryDark

to be more specific change the style xml as

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item> 
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryAcentColor</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

You need to create `attrs.xml` under **values folder**.

Mention all your reference colors inside this file.

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="primaryColor"></attr>
    <attr name="primaryLightColor"></attr>
    <attr name="primaryDarkColor"></attr>
    <attr name="primaryTextColor"></attr>
</resources>
```

Now you can directly use your colors in style.xml

e.g.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="primaryColor">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="primaryLightColor">@color/primaryLightColor</item>
        <item name="primaryDarkColor">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="primaryTextColor">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to define non-exist attribute in your style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="primaryColor">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="primaryLightColor">@color/primaryLightColor</item>
    <item name="primaryDarkColor">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="primaryTextColor">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
</style>
```

There are no `primaryColor`, `primaryLightColor`, `primaryDarkColor`, and `primaryTextColor`. The right attributes are `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark`, `colorPrimaryLight`, and `textColorPrimary`. This image will show you the attributes (from [Using the material theme](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)):

[image]

So, you need to change it to the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryLight">@color/primaryLightColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'colorPrimaryLight'