# Android cannot resolve symbol "primaryLightColor" attribute in styles

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-color

I want to use [Color Tool](https://material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0) for picking colors that will be used in App. After selecting `Primary` and `Secondary` colors and exporting for Android, the output includes:

```
<resources>
  ...
  <color name="primaryLightColorBlue">#534bae</color>
</resources>
```

But when I try to use that in styles like this:

```
<style name="Blue" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
...
<item name="primaryLightColor">@color/primaryLightColorBlue</item>
</style>
```

I  encounter with this error:

```
cannot resolve symbol  "primaryLightColor"
```

Also I tried `colorPrimaryLight` attribute as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47508073/1043882):

```
<item name="colorPrimaryLight">@color/primaryLightColorBlue</item>
```

But again I encounter an error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'colorPrimaryLight'
```

What is correct attribute corresponding to the `primaryLightColor`?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set/override the value `primaryLightColor` for `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar`

That Theme doesn't have that attribute, Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47506269/7968986

So to answer what else you should use: `colorPrimary` for the light one and `colorPrimaryDark` for any "non-light" one

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific list of colors for theming in style. They are :-

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/yourColor</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/yourColor</item>
<item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/yourColor</item>
<!-- Secondary brand color. -->
<item name="colorSecondary">@color/yourColor</item>
<item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/yourColor</item>
<item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/yourColor</item>
<!-- Status bar color. -->
<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/yourColor</item>
<item name="colorSurface">@color/yourColor</item>
<item name="colorOnSurface">@color/yourColor</item>
<item name="colorPrimarySurface">@color/yourColor</item>
<item name="colorError">@color/yourColor</item>
<item name="colorOnError">@color/yourColor</item>
```

**Solution**

For your case we can *tweak* between `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryVariant` one of them will serve as *light* and the other a bit **darker** shade. ( using `colorPrimaryLight` as a variant of `colorPrimary` )

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryLightColorBlue</item>
```