# Android gradle build failed : aapt error 137

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aapt

Randomly, while trying to build my android applications, I have this message during the mergeResources :

Execution failed for task ':ImmoStruct:mergeReleaseResources'.

> Failed to run command:
>       /home/android/adt-bundle/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt s -i /home/android/queue/294c2840260c2d59c396a7e08ac3c32ba045cb28/ImmoStruct/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_find_previous_holo_light.png -o /home/android/queue/294c2840260c2d59c396a7e08ac3c32ba045cb28/ImmoStruct/build/res/all/release/drawable-mdpi/ic_find_previous_holo_light.png
>     Error Code:
>       137

Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it doesn't...

The concerned files are not always the same : ic_find_previous_holo_light.png
common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png
abs__ab_bottom_solid_light_holo.9.png

I tried to change the build version, but the problem remains.

Any idea on the cause, workaround ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359572/android-studio-execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-if-project
check this link

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem too and believe it is related to the gradle deamon.

run
   $./gradlew --stop

prior to your task. it did the trick for me.