# what is app:mergeDebugResources for?

Tags: android

This is happening in FusedPeriodic app 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Crunching Cruncher common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_dark.9.png failed, see logs

Comment: There's a similar question here that suggest you might have long project path, see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359572/android-studio-execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-if-project

Comment: That task, AFAIK, does what its name suggests: it is merging the resources for the debug build, across any relevant sourcesets. The "crunching" references stem from packaging resources into the APK. Beyond that, I agree with Sharj's recommendation.