# Android Studio Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Tags: android, android-studio, nine-patch

I have a problem with 9 patch images.

There are around 30 9 patch images in my res folder. On earlier versions of Android Studio, errors told me exactly which one of the images was bad, but on newer versions I just get error

```
Error:Execution failed for task
 ':app:mergePhotoKeyboardThemeChangerDebugResources'.
 
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

Is there an option for that in Android Studio settings? It is a lot of work to check images one by one and see which one is bad.

Comment: Cannot you view the logs in IDE?

Comment: Only error I am getting is the error above in the question. Earlier I was getting errors with exact location such as "... file test.9.png ... at top edge pixel no 15..."

Comment: Run with `--stacktrace --info` flags. Hopefully this will log something.

Comment: No details on the error. Now I get same log two times.

Comment: What is the complete path of your res folder? Sometimes this error appears when the path is too long.

Comment: It is quite long. But with flag --debug I get detailed error. "ERRORL 9-patch image test.9.png malformed. No marked region found along edge. Found along top edge."

Comment: After updating to Android Studio 2.3.1 flat "--debug" isn't showing the error any more...

Answer (score 1):

Some times the error will come with jpg images, try to convert the jpg images to png images.
convert online from [online png converter](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png).

Comment: No, it is 9.png image. At the moment I made it wrong on purpose just to try to see error.

Comment: I think this is the problem with adt. you can instead rename the *.9.png to *.png

Comment: But I need those images to be 9 patch png. I have found the solution already thank you.

Comment: @filipst what's your solution?

Comment: @Néstor I don't have a solution at the moment. Simple "--debug" was doing the job, but it isn't any more.

Comment: in my case I change a .jpg images to .png from the Window's explorer and put in my app. I just paste the jpg's image without conversion

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion#1:**

Relocate your project and the build will succeed.

Resource Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25209204

**Suggestion#2:**

Sometimes .png images are corrupted. you need to replace in drawable

Resource Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41380118

**Suggestion#3:**
change build directory

For example:

```
allprojects {
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Rebuild and happy coding.

Resource Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41877283

**Last Suggestion**
Add

```
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
```

in your `gradle(app)` file in `android{ }` scope

it will work fine