# Application crashing when I choose a picture and display it on the button (KOTLIN ON CREATE)

Tags: android, kotlin

Im making a register app, that allows the user to pick a picture via button, after the user pressed it, the background of the button should be the chosen picture, but instead it crashes, what could be the problem?

here is the code to open up the image picker via button

```
 button_selectphoto_register.setOnClickListener {
        val intent=Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
    }
```

and here is the onActivityResult that should show the image on the button*/
NOTE: the getBitmap is crossed in android studio, it says that it is deprecated, i think that is what causing the problem, but i dont know what i should do

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){

    val uri = data.data

    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, uri)
    val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
    button_selectphoto_register.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
}
```

Comment: Please post logs.

Comment: Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Comment: is there a way i can change my gradle build version?

Comment: @jake probably meant the stack trace you are getting when the application crashes.

Comment: can you edit your question and put the crash logs there itself.

Comment: i cant seem to find my crash logs, also my logcat is empty when i do something in my app

Comment: Please add --warning-mode all to your Gradle command line.

Comment: how can i add it? im sorry im a newbie to android studio forgive my stupidity

Comment: See [this post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192538/deprecated-gradle-features-making-it-incompatible-with-gradle-5-0-android-studi).

Comment: I'll just ask what's the alternative code for getBitmap in gradle version 5.1.1? because it is deprecated in version 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the alternative code for getBitmap, then follow [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#getBitmap(android.content.ContentResolver,%2520android.net.Uri)) link. As it says,

> This method was deprecated in API level 29. Loading of images should be performed through `ImageDecoder#createSource(ContentResolver, Uri)`