# Spring Tool Suite download and installation

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I've downloaded spring-tool-suite-3.6.1.RELEASE-e4.4-win32-x86_64.zip and getting the following error while trying to unzip and install:

```
Error 0x80010135: Path too long
POM.properties
Type PROPERTIES File
Date Modified 6/11/2014 12:47PM
Size 146 bytes.
```

What may be the reason?

Comment: Try and save it in the `C:/` and see what happens. Seems like you're trying to save it somewhere too deep

Comment: Maybe [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1880321/2587435)

Comment: Thanks for asking this question! I had the same problem.

Answer (score 30):

Possible solutions:

1. Rename `spring-tool-suite-3.6.1.RELEASE-e4.4-win32-x86_64.zip` to `springts.zip`
2. Move `spring-tool-suite-3.6.1.RELEASE-e4.4-win32-x86_64.zip` to `C:/` or in another location that is not very deep.
3. Change your extractor to **7-zip**.

Comment: I did a combination of #1 and #2.  I put the zip folder in a folder I created at the C drive, so this was my path `C:/STS`.  I renamed the zip file to `STS-3.6.1.zip`.  That fixed the path too long issue.  I am using Windows 10 and was able to use the native zip program to extract.

Comment: A simpler version: right-click on downloaded zip, click on "Extract All..." and simply change the name of the new folder the contents are extracted to.  I changed `C:\Tools\spring-tool-suite-3.9.2.RELEASE-e4.7.2-win32-x86_64` to simply `C:\Tools\sts-3.9.2` and averted any error msg.

Comment: 7zip works well... also I extracted in Downloads folder itself

Comment: 7zip is pretty much fine.

Comment: When I changed winzip for 7zip, then work well. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

Try with any alternative for zip such as **7Zip** or **WinRAR**. *7Zip* worked for me

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the zip file name being too long.You can rename the downloaded zip file to something like STS.zip (Give a short name) and then try to extract it.The error should now disappear.

Answer (score 0):

When you extract, it will try to extract in a folder named "spring-tool-suite-3.6.1.RELEASE-e4.4-win32-x86_64" which is too long for a folder name. Simple rule of thumb -- install to C:\ and rename the above to STS361_x8664. Be very frugal with folder names.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the file name & path are too long.
Rename them to something smaller and simpler.

[Here is the link that I found helpful](https://geeznblogged.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/are-you-facing-total-path-and-file-name-length-must-not-exceed-260-characters-error-while-unzipping/)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download STS  zip file from spring official website

Step 2: After downloading Spring Tool Suite zip file then extract that then Open STS directory file click on STS icon below like this.

Step 3:  Run that file then Select a directory as a workspace and browse your directory.

Here is complete installations of STS on Windows operating system.

Source : http://commandstech.com/how-to-install-springtoolsuitests-with-scala-on-windows-7-8-10/