# Running programs from command prompt (PATH environment variable)

Tags: windows, path, command-prompt

I'm having some issues when trying to run some programs from the command prompt after adding their executable file paths to the PATH variable. I respected the syntax (; at the end of every path added). Has this ever happened to anyone?

Comment: Which your issue? It's not clear

Comment: How long is your path? It has a max limit.

Comment: Does it say something like `'foo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0):

You have not told us what problem you are seeing, but it you append the path to a program at the end of PATH thus:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"c:\somewhere_else"
```

you can find the new path nevers gets seen, since there's a hard upper limit on path length. See for example this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows)

One option is to prepend the new location, bearing in mind this will drop other things off the end:

```
set PATH="c:\somewhere_else";%PATH%
```

There are various workrounds. For example, I tend to have a few `set_path.bat` files in a few different locations that reset my path to what's required for various different tasks.