# Deploying to Android results in file not found after adding QtQuick Controls

Tags: android, qt, deployment, qml, qt5.4

After importing `QtQuick.Controls 1.2` and using `StackedWidget` component, I now get an error when deploying to Android as seen below. The missing file `AnimationDrawable.qml` is not missing from the Android build directory so I do not understand why it is not packaged with the APK.

It deploys fine when I remove the imported `QtQuick.Controls` and replace the `StackView` with something else.

My Qt version is 5.4.2.

I tried deploying it with Qt 5.3.2 and it works as expected.

```html
E/Qt      (12767): Can't create main activity
E/Qt      (12767): java.io.FileNotFoundException: --Added-by-androiddeployqt--/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Android/drawables/AnimationDrawable.qml
E/Qt      (12767):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
E/Qt      (12767):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
E/Qt      (12767):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:287)
E/Qt      (12767):  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.copyAsset(QtActivity.java:394)
E/Qt      (12767):  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.extractBundledPluginsAndImports(QtActivity.java:503)
E/Qt      (12767):  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.startApp(QtActivity.java:582)
E/Qt      (12767):  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:895)
E/Qt      (12767):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
E/Qt      (12767):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
E/Qt      (12767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
E/Qt      (12767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
E/Qt      (12767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
E/Qt      (12767):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
E/Qt      (12767):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/Qt      (12767):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/Qt      (12767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
E/Qt      (12767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/Qt      (12767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/Qt      (12767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
E/Qt      (12767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: If you're on windows, I have guess: the path becomes too long (>256 characters is a real problem for windows). This only happens when importing QtQuick because then the Styles folder will be deployed. Try to install Qt as top level as possible on your system to make the paths shorter. That should do it!

Comment: @qCring: Qt is installed in C:/Qt/*, but the project is kind of in a deep path. Might that cause the same behaviour? And I just verified it works on Qt 5.3.2

Comment: Yeah I guess the same applies for destination paths. I would give it a try!

Comment: @qCring: Holy smokes, it worked! This kind of issue feels so unnecesarry.. The reason it worked for 5.3.2 must be that its path was 5 character shorter ("lucky"). Write and answer if you want to and I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When deploying the application, `androiddeployqt` will copy a bunch of files which terribly fails on Windows when source or destination paths become longer than 260 characters (yeah, that's a "[known feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1880453/2538363)"). Keeping the Qt installation and the project directory as top level as possible helps to reduce the path lengths and solves the problem. And that's basically it!