# Shutil.copy IO Error2 when directory exists

Tags: python, windows, io, shutil, max-path

I'm encountering a troublesome problem with my code and I've been unable to figure it out. Basically I am copying files from a local directory on my computer to a Dropbox folder that acts as a project repository for me and some other folks.

I keep hitting an IO Error when executing the shutil.copy line. Errno 2, N osuch file or directory. However the directory and file both exist. When I change the directory to a different/test location (test_dir in my code), the code runs perfectly fine. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
import os, os.path
import re
import shutil
import sys

#File Location
directory_list = "path where files are located"

#Dropbox base directory: 
dropbox = "path to dropbox directory"

test_dir = "path to test directory on my local machine"    

sed_files = os.listdir(directory_list)

for i in sed_files:
    #print i.split("BBB")[0]

    #df
    copy_dir = re.sub(r'XXX',r'_',i.split("BBB")[0])
    copy_dir = re.sub(r'ZZZ',r'/',copy_dir)
    copy_dir = dropbox + copy_dir + "/FIXED/"   
    if not os.path.exists(copy_dir):
        os.makedirs(copy_dir)       

    shutil.copy(directory_list+i,copy_dir)
    #print directory_list+i
    #os.rename(copy_dir+i,copy_dir+i.split("BBB")[1])
```

Traceback error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "copy_SE_files.py", line 25, in <module> shutil.copy(direcotry_list+i,copydir)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\shutil.py", line 116, in copy copyfile(src,dst)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/myusername/Dropbox/NASA_HyspIRI_Project/Field_Data/Spectra/CVARS/April2014/LemonTrees/04172014_SE_LemonTreeCanopy/SE_Files/SpectraZZZCVARSZZZApril2014ZZZLemonTreesZZZZ04172014XXXSEXXXLemonTreeCanopyZZZSEXXXFilesBBBCVARS_na_LemonTrees_Bareground1_4deg_Refl_00355.sed'
```

Problem solved thanks to the keen eyes of stack overflow. Modified the line to read:

```
shutil.copy(directory_list+i,'\\\\?\\'+os.path.abspath(copy_dir))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1880480/2141635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're failing because the combined length of the path is greater than Window's `MAX_PATH` limit. `C:/Users/myusername/Dropbox/NASA_HyspIRI_Project/Field_Data/Spectra/CVARS/April2014/LemonTrees/04172014_SE_LemonTreeCanopy/SE_Files/SpectraZZZCVARSZZZApril2014ZZZLemonTreesZZZZ04172014XXXSEXXXLemonTreeCanopyZZZSEXXXFilesBBBCVARS_na_LemonTrees_Bareground1_4deg_Refl_00355.sed` is 274 characters long, and without going to some trouble, most Windows file manipulation APIs won't work properly with a path longer than `MAX_PATH` (which is 260, and one of them is reserved for the `NUL` terminator).

Assuming Python uses the correct APIs, you can make it work with [the extended path prefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#maxpath), `\\?\` (and it may require you to use backslashes rather than forward slashes in your path; I'm not clear on that; read the docs).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumped out at me was this line:

```
shutil.copy(directory_list+i,copy_dir)
```

Consider changing it to

```
shutil.copy(os.path.join(directory_list,i),copy_dir)
```

IOW, use `os.path.join()` when concatenating file paths.

Answer (score 0):

One work around is:

```
try:
    shutil.copy(src, dest)
except:
   try:
       shutil.copy(src, "\\\\?\\" + dest)
       #If Long Path as per Maximum Path limitation Windows
   except:
       self.failed_TC=True
       print("Failed to move the script "+os.path.basename(src)+" to "+dest)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add some explanation for your code?