# Laravel elixir always error when install and Gulp error

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-elixir

I try to install laravel elixir (version ^4.0.0), every time i install it always have this error:

[image: error 1]

And everytime i run the `gulp`:

[image]

I've tried install using `npm install --no-bin-links` but still no luck.

My gulpfile.js:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
    elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;

    elixir(function (mix) {
         .browserify('app.module.js', 'public/app/app.module.js');
    }
```

Any help will be great!.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows seems windows has a character limit on the path. You could maybe shorten the folder name of your project to get under that character limit. If not possibly raise a bug on the socket.io module.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/69

Comment: Hi @MarkDavidson . Thanks for great link!. It really help me. Looks like it is windows problem. Will try those solution at link.

Comment: @MarkDavidson any solution about the second one?