# When TestClass Name & Namespace length reaches 128 characters, the test class shows as 'Excluded' in Test Explorer when PostSharp is referenced

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, postsharp, test-explorer

I recently created a VS2015 solution to migrate projects & test projects from VS2010. I am experiencing odd behaviour with one particular test class which has a reference to PostSharp, where the combined namespace and test class name reaches 128 characters (which isn't many in my opinion). The tests show as 'excluded' in the test explorer window (When the tests are grouped by project). Also when I right click within the test class, the output window shows 'No tests found to run'.

When I try to select the test methods within the 'external' node, the following test is displayed: 'Source: no source available'.

I have tried creating another test project in a different solution, and purposely exceeded the 128 characters without postsharp and the problem goes away.

The obvious fix for this is to shorten the length of the namespace, however I am curious as to whether anyone has ever found a reason / solution for this?

Comment: Probably has something to do with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows).  Do what works.

Comment: I think this would be a good question to post to the postsharp forums themselves.

Comment: Agree with @Batavia. Please, could you add an example project if you ask the question on PostSharp forum? It works for me in a very minimal unit test project.