# How do I compile a nodejs file using nexe on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio, compilation

So I see there is quite a few people who have gotten a similar issue. The only difference being, everyone seems to have a different fix for this code. Short summary of what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to compile a nodejs file using nexe. When I compile on my linux machine, it works fine. However I need to compile it on a windows machine. When I try to do this, it produces this error in the console:

```
  FAILED: ..\..\Release\icupkg -tl ..\..\deps\icu-small\source\data\in\icudt57l.
dat C:\Users\Kohdy Nicholson\Code\Node\Eyereturn\tmp\nexe\nodejs\latest\node-v6.
2.1\Release\obj\global_intermediate\icutmp\icudt57l.dat
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targe
ts(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\Users\Kohdy Nicholso
n\Code\Node\Eyereturn\tmp\nexe\nodejs\latest\node-v6.2.1\tools\icu\icudata.vcxpr
oj]
  v8_nosnapshot.vcxproj -> ..\..\..\..\build\Release\lib\v8_nosnapshot.lib
  icui18n.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Kohdy Nicholson\Code\Node\Eyereturn\tmp\nexe\nodej
s\latest\node-v6.2.1\Release\lib\icui18n.lib
  icustubdata.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Kohdy Nicholson\Code\Node\Eyereturn\tmp\nexe\n
odejs\latest\node-v6.2.1\Release\lib\icustubdata.lib
  openssl-cli.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Kohdy Nicholson\Code\Node\Eyereturn\tmp\nexe\n
odejs\latest\node-v6.2.1\Release\\openssl-cli.exe
....> ERROR: The release executable has not been generated. This indicates a fai
lure in the build process. There is likely additional information above.
```

My question is, how can I possibly overcome this error? I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 15. I've installed the Visual C++ compiler associated with it. I've installed python 2.7. I also have the most recent version of node 6.2 and npm 3.9. I am using the latest version of ICU 57 as well. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Is your question How do I compile a nodejs file using nexe on Windows?  If so I would encourage you to edit the title

Comment: Yes, title has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar problem (on both Windows and Cygwin) which is caused by the [260 character limitation on Windows path names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows).

To work around this, I moved the project into my User directory - this shortened the intermediate paths sufficiently to allow nexe to run to completion.

Comment: Okay thanks! I actually just decided to compile using jxcore in the end. But if I ever decide to try out nexe again, I'll definitely try your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue. for me it was a space in the filename. I see you could have the same issue ... 'C:\Users\Kohdy Nicholson\Code.......'.