# npm 3.5.2 nuget package fails to install in VS2013

Tags: npm, nuget

I am unable to install nuget package `NPM 3.5.2` in visual studio 2013. It fails with error - `Could not find a part of the path`

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Node.js (≥ 0.12.7)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'NoGit (≥ 0.1.0)'.
Installing 'Npm 3.5.2'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\92236435-c19e-4785-96ed-e1434682490e\stzkys2q.h4q\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream-npm\node_modules\fstream-ignore\node_modules\minimatch\node_modules\brace-expansion\node_modules\balanced-match\.npmignore'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're bumping into the windows maximum path length which is 260 chars:
This explains:
 [Why does the 260 character path length limit exist in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows)

Comment: No. I guess this is a different issue. I tried even installing in c:\abc\ folder. I still get the same error.

Comment: I have successfully added that package to a vs2013 solution, but only if i put my project in a shorter path length. I can get this error if i use the default path under your user path which is too long (if you use vs2015 it even tells you that this is the case).