# Symfony2 development environment breaks often / Permission denied / Doctrine file cache

Tags: php, windows, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with my Symfony2 REST API and the Doctrine cache.
Normally I would say there is no problem with files... I owned a SSD which is only used for those projects. But there is a problem with it... :-(

```
Warning: fopen(C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\var\\cache\\dev\\annotations\\0b\\5b4361666542756e646c655c456e746974795c4361666523676574506963747572655468756d62353535783431355d5b315d.doctrinecache.data): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

This is what I get after this history:

```
OPTIONS /api/user/get
GET /api/user/get
OPTIONS /api/stats/get
GET /api/stats/get
OPTIONS /api/group/get
GET /api/group/get
OPTIONS /api/credit/get
GET /api/credit/get
OPTIONS /api/players/get
GET /api/players/get [X] Crash
```

This is a sample scenario.
Sometimes after few requests (not hundreds!) I get this cache problem and the requests hangs.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this? - Except switching to productive mode?

Thanks in Advance for ideas!

Comment: Yeah, I think its a windows issue. I have been this getting on occasion for months on my Windows machine mostly in Dev env, but less frequently in Prod env. No issue on Linux though.

Comment: Windows has problem with long paths and long file names, it depends of which version and what configuration of Windows you have. Symfony cache files has long names sometimes. Maybe your problem could be related with this issue. If you are using Windows as web server take a look this question to fix path and file length limitation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows