# Unable to iterate around folders and pipe them to try/catch

Tags: powershell

I have a super annoying problem, where I am basically doing the following:

```
Get-ChildItem $rootPath -Recurse | 
    Where {$_.psiscontainer} | 
        Get-Acl | % { 
            Write-Host "Doing some stuff here" 
        }
```

But I occasionally get an error when calling `Get-Acl` saying that I don't have access.

That is fine, I can just catch the error and continue right?

So i tried

```
Get-ChildItem $rootPath -Recurse | 
    Where {$_.psiscontainer} | 
        try {
            Get-Acl | % { 
                Write-Host "Doing some stuff here" 
            }
        } catch {Write-Host "error"}
```

But now I get

> the term 'try' is not recognized

Which is unbelievably unhelpful, since `try` definitely is a command in PowerShell...

Next I tried to split the command out like so

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem $rootPath -Recurse | Where {$_.psiscontainer}

foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    try {
        Get-Acl | % { 
            Write-Host "Doing some stuff here" 
        }
    } catch {write-host "error"}
}
```

Now i'm getting

> Get-childitem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name 
>   must be less than 248 characters.

**WHY?** And how am I supposed to check **which folder is failing?**

Comment: Not every command accepts pipeline input. You could do `GCI $rootfolder -directory |ForEach{try{Get-Acl $_|<Do Stuff>}Catch{"Error"}}`. As for your path that is too long, you should be able to check `$errors` to see what it path it threw the error on.

Comment: `Try` isn't a command, it's a keyword. You can't pipe into `try` like you can't pipe into ([get-help about_language_keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-6)) `return` or `break` or `InlineScript`. "**WHY?**" - why the limit exists? Backwards compatibility - https://stackoverflow.com/q/1880321/478656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try something like:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem $rootPath -Recurse -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    try {
        Get-Acl -Path $folder | % { 
            Write-Host "Doing some stuff here" 
        }
    } catch {write-host "error"}
}
```

where you can use `-Directory` and also continue on errors (`ErrorAction`).

Also, you need to pass arguments to Get-Acl now that you have unrolled the pipeline (a good move for debugging).