# Error while installing JupyterLab with pip Windows

Tags: pip, jupyter-lab

I face the below error while trying to install package dependencies for JupyterLab via pip.

```
Installing collected packages: jedi, ipython, ipykernel, notebook, jupyterlab-server, jupyterlab  
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\<Username>\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python37\\site-packages\\jedi\\third_party\\typeshed\\third_party\\2and3\\requests\\packages\\urllib3\\packages\\ssl_match_hostname\\_implementation.pyi'
```

**EDIT** : All these packages have dependencies on Jedi, and I'm unable to  install Jedi. Can someone help how I can remove this SSL hostname error?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with the pathname being too long. Uninstalled and reinstalled python, removed restriction on path variable length. And done, solved.

Comment: I found this post useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624449/python-setup-disabling-path-length-limit-pros-and-cons

Answer (score 0):

When you are installing Python is important to "Disable path length limit" , and that it's!

[image]