# Does pyperclip have a maximum of characters?

Tags: python, pyperclip

I have a problem using pyperclip. I have to upload a bunch of documents to the web. I used the join method to make a string of the files contained in a specific folder. The problem comes when that string reaches 260 characters. pyperclip copies up to 260, the rest is not copied. 
Is there a way I can change this? Or another method I can use?

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
cell1 = str(cell1)
my_path = "C:\Users\\"+user+"\Desktop\folder\\"+cell1
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir("C:\Users\\"+user+"\Desktop\folder\\"+cell1) if isfile(join(my_path, f))]
for doc in onlyfiles:
    doc = '" "'.join(map(str, onlyfiles))
    docs = '"' + doc + '"'
print docs
time.sleep(1)
#copiar directorio
from pyperclip import copy
copy(my_path)
keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
keyboard.press('v')
keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
keyboard.release('v')
time.sleep(1.5)
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

Comment: Your code snippet is not complete since you show no import for `keyboard`. Please show a complete example, as in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It also is not wise to directly import the `copy` function into your namespace, since that is such a common method name. Better to use `import pyperclip` and `pyperclip.copy(my_path)`. Have you tried using pyperclip with longer strings in a simpler example?

Comment: (I'm sorry if I have any grammatical mistake, I'm a Spanish speaker). The keyboard import is in the beginning of my code, that is why I did not paste it. There is sensible information in the middle.
This is a task I have been working for my job, and I want to try it for what it is thought for: mass upload of documents to the web.
I'll add import pyperclip and pyperclip.copy(my_path). Thanks!

Comment: I'm the creator of Pyperclip and can vouch that it doesn't have a built-in limit. On Windows 10, Python 3.7, I can run this to confirm it:

>>> import pyperclip
>>> pyperclip.copy('x' * 10000)
>>> len(pyperclip.paste())
10000

Comment: Hi! I found out that there is a limit of characters in the space where I have to paste the string I made with all the names of the documents contained in a certain folder. So now I'm dealing with another trouble. What I'm going to do is write a loop in order to upload documents every x quantity. It's going to be tedious, but I just can't bear the idea of controlling the keyboard to type a "CTRL"+"A", and use "TAB" because is embarrassing! haha!
THANKS for your response!! I'll be migrating to W10 in a month (sorry for the typo), so I hope everything is going to behave properly! =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting truncated file names from `listdir` - there is apparently a [260 character path length limit on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows).

Comment: Is there a way I can change that on W7? I'm no programmer, I've barely started with Python a few months ago.

Comment: [This blog post](https://www.burgaud.com/path-too-long) says there might be a workaround - prefix the path with "\\?\". Change `my_path = "C:\\...` to `my_path = "\\\\?\\C:\\...` and see if it helps