# FileNotFoundError when opening a file with absoulute path

Tags: python, file, directory

I am trying to iteratively open some files to do some processing with the data. However, I haven't been able to make it work. I don't know what could be causing this.

```
sd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

file_names = []
for root,d_names,f_names in os.walk(os.path.join(sd, path)):
    for f in f_names:
        if f.endswith('.csv'):
            file_names.append(os.path.join(root, f))

for f_name in file_names:
    with open(f_name, 'r') as file:
        ...
```

I have also tried the following aproach, using `pathlib`

```
input_path = pathlib.Path(path)
file_names = input_path.glob('**/*.csv')

for f_name in file_names:
    with open(f_name.resolve(), 'r') as file:
        ...
```

Both methods yield the same result.

'path' is the name of a directory that sits on the same directory as the script. Reading the error seems to indicate the path is correct. The files sit in a somewhat complex file structure with pretty long filenames at times.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\...
```

To give a bit more insight, here is a brief simplified representation of the file structure of `path`

```
path
¦-dir1
¦¦-dir2
¦¦¦-dir3
¦¦¦¦-sub1
¦¦¦¦¦-file-1a
¦¦¦¦-sub2
¦¦¦¦¦-file-1b
¦¦¦¦¦-file-2b
```

What I've found by testing is that when I replace `path` by `dir3` to remove uneccessary traversal, the script will process `file-1a` which is the only one in that directory and `file-1b`, but give the same error when reaching `file-2b`. Furthermore, when making `sub2` the target instead, it will process all files inside `sub2` with no issues.

Also, as suggested, I tried adding the line `print(os.access(f_name, os.R_OK), repr(f_name))` just before attempting to open the file. It turns out it returns `False` every time just before the error is raised(followed by the file path), and returns `True` whenever I've managed to process a file.

Comment: why don't you use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). with `pathlib` you can use `Path(path).glob('*.csv')`

Comment: The script dir isn't necessarily the same as the cwd. Get the script dir like this: `sd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`. Then do `os.walk(os.path.join(sd, path))`. There is no need to join the paths again when you open the files, since they should already be absolute.

Comment: @deadshot Thanks, I like that implementation.Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to fix te error.

Comment: what are error are you getting when you are using `pathlib`

Comment: @ekhumoro I see your point. I just tried it out however and the result unfortunately seems to be the same. I've been checking the paths manually and they look correct. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @deadshot Exactly the same error. I also tried `.resolve()` but nothing different apart from it being an absolute path.

Comment: `Path.glob()` don't throw an error if the path not exist it will return empty generator

Comment: @deadshot Right, I tried iterating through as a test and it seems to be working fine, returning paths to the files I expected. The problem is when I try to open them for some reason.

Comment: can you share the code you have tried

Comment: @deadshot I've updated the question with the latest version of both methods I've tried, one of them being the pathlib aproach.

Comment: try this `for file in file_names:
    with file.open() as fp:`

Comment: @deadshot Unfortunately, same error.

Comment: @ABenju I just did a sanity check on the first example and it works fine for me on linux. That is, I created a directory called "tmp" with some csv files in it, put it in the same directory as the script, and then set `path = 'tmp'`. All the files were read without any errors.

Comment: @ABenju As an extra test, please add the line `print(os.access(f_name, os.R_OK), repr(f_name))` to the beginning of the second for-loop and show the output you get.

Comment: @ekhumoro I've updated the question to show the results from your suggestion as well as a strange finding I made by testing. I'll try on a different system when I get a chance, I'm starting to think it might have something to do with it. I've also tried moving the entire project to a different directory just in case, with no result.

Comment: @ABenju For backward-compatibility reasons, Windows uses a maximum path length of 260 characters. That's partly why I asked you to show the `repr` of the file names. Please always show the full results in your question when asked for debugging output. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1880321/984421) for more information on this issue and some possible work-arounds.

Comment: @ekhumoro apologies, I'll keep it in mind for other questions. You seem to be spot on! I wasn't aware of the fact. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @ekhumoro for pointing me in the right direction.

It seems my paths were longer than 260 characters, which is by default not allowed by Windows for backwards-compatibility reasons.

I changed the Windows registry to allow long paths and now my script has no issues accessing all the files in the structure.