# auth_registrations_mapping error: could not create while pip install twilio on cmd with admin access

Tags: python, twilio

Note: Most of the solutions to similar problem suggest that, I retry on CMD admin access. I have tried and still it wont install and returns similar error.

```
SoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\sip\domain\auth_types\auth_registrations_mapping
    error: could not create 'C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\sip\domain\auth_types\auth_registrations_mapping\auth_registrations_credential_list_mapping.py': No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6lxfxplk\\twilio_26ffaa2a98754c52996da5165593b5ba\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6lxfxplk\\twilio_26ffaa2a98754c52996da5165593b5ba\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ovyqxs5v\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\twilio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe you have hit the [Windows path length limit of 260 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows), which is why this file is failing. You can enable longer paths by [following the instructions in the Windows documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd).

Essentially, the `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled (Type: REG_DWORD)` registry key must exist and be set to 1. Then, after a reboot you should be able to use longer paths and your installation should succeed.

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind hitting the tick to accept the answer so that other people can see this helped too? Thanks!