# Attempt to build project results in path error. Path length is too long. Will moving this file change any references or dependencies I have?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, babeljs

The error below is what is generated when I attempt to build the solution. How should this be handled? Should I change path? Will any references or dependencies need to be mapped?

| Severity | Code | Description | Project | File | Line | Suppression State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Error | MSB4248 | Cannot expand metadata in expression "$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('%(FullPath)', '').StartsWith($([MSBuild]::EnsureTrailingSlash($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))))". The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "wwwroot\react-chp\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\node_modules%40babel\preset-env\node_modules%40babel\plugin-proposal-numeric-separator\node_modules%40babel\core\node_modules.bin\parser". Path: C:\Users\Jabari.LAPTOP-FERO3UB5\Desktop\Work\codebase\CHP\Presentation\Chp.Web\wwwroot\react-chp\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\node_modules@babel\preset-env\node_modules@babel\plugin-proposal-numeric-separator\node_modules@babel\core\node_modules.bin\parser exceeds the OS max path limit. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters. | C:\Users\Jabari.LAPTOP-FERO3UB5\Desktop\Work\codebase\CHP\Presentation\Chp.Web\Chp.Web.csproj | C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets | 100 |  |

Comment: Which version of Windows? I seem to recall this is no longer an issue in modern Windows

Comment: perhaps one of the answers [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows) helps?

Comment: I'm currently using Windows 11.

Comment: Oh, I guess you could try one of the solutions in that other question then

Comment: New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" `
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force                                          pasting in the powershell worked for me.  Thank you