# How do I recursively grep all directories and subdirectories?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

How do I recursively `grep` all directories and subdirectories?

```
find . | xargs grep "texthere" *
```

Comment: @TC1 The sad thing is that grep itself can answer the question (at least GNU grep): grep --help |grep recursive

Comment: If you find yourself frequently using grep to do recursive searches (especially if you manually do a lot of file/directory exlusions), you may find [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) (a very programmer-friendly grep alternative) useful.

Comment: Actually neither -r nor --recursive work on the Solaris box I use at work. And the man page for grep doesn't mention anything recursive. I had to resort to find and xargs myself.

Comment: ag is my favorite way to do this now https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher

Comment: `grep -rin xlsx *.pl` doesn't work for me on Redhat Linux. I get a "no match" error.

Comment: The * on the end is a mistake isn't it?  

The shell will expand that to add all the files and directories in the current directory as parameters to the to the grep command, rather than allowing only xargs to provide the file name

Comment: If your gonna mention Silver Searcher (ag) then you gotta mention RipGrep: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12564442

Comment: The final "*" is not needed, xargs feeds the filenames to the grep command in suitable chunks not to overload the max allowed number of characters for a command line.

Comment: recursively in this context means that we search inside folders inside the folder we are standing in?

Answer (score 3142, accepted):

```
grep -r "texthere" .
```

The first parameter represents the regular expression to search for, while the second one represents the directory that should be searched. In this case, `.` means the current directory.

Note: This works for GNU grep, and on some platforms like Solaris you must specifically use GNU grep as opposed to legacy implementation.  For Solaris this is the `ggrep` command.

Comment: Note: "grep -r" only works on newer greps. It doesn't work on the grep that comes with `AIX 5.3` for example.

Comment: Use grep -R to follow symlinks.

Comment: On Cygwin, to also search for hidden files (that begin with a dot) and inside them, you need to use `find . -type f | xargs grep -l "search string"`. `grep -r` alone on Cygwin does not search hidden files.

Comment: It is good to know that "-i" would make it case insensitive, and "-n" also include the line number for each matched result.

Comment: also good to know, if you are just looking for a fixed string and not a regex, use -F option.  it will save you scads of time by not invoking the regex parser.  very handy if you are searching lots of files.

Comment: alias rgrep='grep -r'

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, because the question has the tag "unix" and it does not work for a lot of Unixes, including HP-UX and AIX (it should work on Linuxes though). Instead, those OS need to use the find command like explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24917/141272

Comment: What happens if the `.` was omitted?

Comment: You can use `-o` to only output the matching text. This is helpful if you have really long lines in the files you're searching (like minified code) and are mostly interested in the files, not the surrounding context.

Comment: in .bash_aliases put rgrepi() {
   grep -i -r --include "${2:-*}" $1 ${3:-.}
}

Comment: When doing this recursively, I often want to know the file where the contents are. You can get this by adding option `--with-filename`.

Comment: What if i want grep to keep polling a file so that when the specific text i am looking for is written to it, grep can find it?

Comment: are the quotations needed? perhaps it would be nice to add that.

Comment: So, typically we want something like `grep -RiFn3 "texthere" .`

Comment: I had to switch the order or the arguments because there was a directory in root with the same name as the search term.
`grep text -r .`

Answer (score 868):

If you know the extension or pattern of the file you would like, another method is to use `--include` option:

```
grep -r --include "*.txt" texthere .
```

You can also mention files to exclude with `--exclude`.

#### Ag

If you frequently search through code, [Ag (The Silver Searcher)](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) is a much faster alternative to grep, that's customized for searching code. For instance, it's recursive by default and automatically ignores files and directories listed in `.gitignore`, so you don't have to keep passing the same cumbersome exclude options to grep or find.

Comment: Works great with grep that comes with Linux & Cygwin, but not with the one that comes with AIX.

Comment: @KrzysztofWolny: ` ` instead of `=` works just fine on Ubuntu. PS: that's supposed to be a backticked space, but the SO markdown parser failed.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I upvoted for the `grep`, not for the Ag, just so you know :)

Comment: Do we have an option to exclude a directory while searching recursively?

Comment: Windows **cygwin** likes double-quotes `--include "*.txt" --include "*.TXT"`

Comment: In .bash_aliases put the one-liner `rgrepi() {
   grep -i -r --include "${2:-*}" $1 ${3:-.}
}`  Then you can do: `rgrepi texthere ; rgrepi texthere '*.txt' ; rgrepi texthere '*.txt' ~/Downloads` ;  to respectively recursively search everything ; recursively search a file pattern ; recursively search a file pattern in a specific directory

Comment: There is an `--exclude-dir` option for excluding directories when searching recursively

Answer (score 167):

I now always use (even on Windows with [GoW -- Gnu on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki)):

```
grep --include="*.xxx" -nRHI "my Text to grep" *
```

(As noted by [kronen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216161/kronen) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively/14871646?noredirect=1#comment117832205_14871646), you can add `2>/dev/null`  to void permission denied outputs)

That includes the following options:

```
--include=PATTERN
```

> Recurse in directories only searching file matching `PATTERN`.

```
-n, --line-number
```

> Prefix each line of output with the line number within its input file.

(Note: [phuclv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995714/phuclv) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively/14871646?noredirect=1#comment95804259_14871646) that  [`-n` decreases performance a lot so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12630617/6309), so you might want to skip that option)

```
-R, -r, --recursive
```

> Read all files under each directory, recursively; this is equivalent to the `-d recurse` option.

```
-H, --with-filename
```

> Print the filename for each match.

```
-I
```

> Process a binary file as if it did not  contain  matching data;
> this is equivalent to the `--binary-files=without-match` option.

And I can add '`i`' (`-nRHIi`), if I want case-insensitive results.

I can get:

```
/home/vonc/gitpoc/passenger/gitlist/github #grep --include="*.php" -nRHI "hidden" *
src/GitList/Application.php:43:            'git.hidden'      => $config->get('git', 'hidden') ? $config->get('git', 'hidden') : array(),
src/GitList/Provider/GitServiceProvider.php:21:            $options['hidden'] = $app['git.hidden'];
tests/InterfaceTest.php:32:        $options['hidden'] = array(self::$tmpdir . '/hiddenrepo');
vendor/klaussilveira/gitter/lib/Gitter/Client.php:20:    protected $hidden;
vendor/klaussilveira/gitter/lib/Gitter/Client.php:170:     * Get hidden repository list
vendor/klaussilveira/gitter/lib/Gitter/Client.php:176:        return $this->hidden;
...
```

Comment: Gow looks promising - newer than the GNU Windows utilities that I have been using. Trying it now...

Comment: what is the meaning of the last character * here?

Comment: @lorniper it makes the shell select all files and folders in your current directory, making in turn the grep apply to those files and (recursively because of the `-R` option) to the folders.

Comment: @lorniper Noy exactly: `*` or `.` is a glob pattern (interpreted by the shell): http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64695/7490. '`.`' will select dotfiles or dot folders as well (like `.git/`)

Comment: previously I've always used `grep -rnI` but then I learned that [`-n` decreases performance a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12630617/995714) so I just use it when really needed and normally I'll use `-rI`

Comment: @phuclv Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I would add `2>/dev/null` to void permission denied outputs

Comment: @Kronen Thank you, good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 141):

Also:

```
find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "foo"
```

but `grep -r` is a better answer.

Comment: Or if you don't want to worry about spaces in filenames `find . -type f -exec grep "foo" '{}' \;` works well where supported.

Comment: If you are going to pipe find through xargs to grep, AND if you are only searching for a fixed string (i.e., not a regex), you might benefit from invoking the grep -F option, so grep won't load the regex engine for each invocation.  If there are a lot of files it will be much faster.

Comment: find . -type f -exec grep -Hu "foo" {} \; is what I use as it gives the filename.

Comment: This works on all *nix because it is [POSIX 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html)

Comment: `find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "foo"`

Comment: this was actually a beter solution for me because grep -r took forever. This might be because grep -r was searching hidden files (of which i had a ton) and maybe find was skipping them.

find also, showed the file name next to each found line, which was important to me

Comment: @EddSteel Is there a particular reason you have quoted the placeholder like so: `'{}'`? On GNU and FreeBSD find it some seems to handle spaces just fine either way.

Comment: @HaroldFischer just reflex/paranoia :)

Answer (score 36):

#### [globbing `**`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option)

Using `grep -r` works, but it may overkill, especially in large folders.

For more practical usage, here is the syntax which uses [globbing syntax](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) (`**`):

```
grep "texthere" **/*.txt
```

which greps only specific files with pattern selected pattern. It works for supported shells such as *Bash +4* or *zsh*.

To activate this feature, run: `shopt -s globstar`.

See also: [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956810/55075)

#### [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)

For projects under Git version control, use:

```
git grep "pattern"
```

which is much quicker.

#### [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

For larger projects, the quickest grepping tool is [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) which greps files recursively by default:

```
rg "pattern" .
```

It's built on top of [Rust's regex engine](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/regex) which uses finite automata, SIMD and aggressive literal optimizations to make searching very fast. Check the [detailed analysis here](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/).

Comment: Thanks for the git grep suggestion -- it is very useful and I did not know about it!

Comment: Thanks for the ripgrep suggestion.  It's way faster.

Answer (score 29):

In POSIX systems, you don't find `-r` parameter for `grep` and your `grep -rn "stuff" .` won't run, but if you use `find` command it will:

`find . -type f -exec grep -n "stuff" {} \; -print`

Agreed by `Solaris` and `HP-UX`.

Comment: what is the meaning of {} \; -print respectively?

Comment: In `-exec` option - symbol `{}` is a reference to the filename which currently found by `find` tool (that is to do something with the filename we found), also `-exec` option should be terminated with `;` symbol (to mark ending of the exec commands), but because this is all running in a shell that symbol should be escaped.. and finally `-print` option lets `find` tool to print out found filenames on the screen.

Answer (score 15):

another syntax to grep a string in all files on a Linux system recursively

```
grep -irn "string"
```

a breakdown of the command

```
 -r, --recursive
```

> indicates a `recursive` search that finds the specified string in the given directory and sub directory looking for the specific string in files, binary, etc

```
-i, --ignore-case
```

> ignore case sensitive, can be used to add inverted case string

```
-n, --line-number
```

> prints the line number of the specified string in the file found

NB: this prints massive result to the console so you might need to filter the output by piping and remove less interesting bits of info. It also searches binary programs so you might want to filter some of the results

Answer (score 14):

If you only want to follow actual directories, and not symbolic links,

```
grep -r "thingToBeFound" directory
```

If you want to follow symbolic links as well as actual directories (be careful of infinite recursion),

```
grep -R "thing to be found" directory
```

Since you're trying to grep recursively, the following options may also be useful to you:

```
-H: outputs the filename with the line

-n: outputs the line number in the file
```

So if you want to find all files containing Darth Vader in the current directory or any subdirectories and capture the filename and line number, but do not want the recursion to follow symbolic links, the command would be

```
grep -rnH "Darth Vader" .
```

If you want to find all mentions of the word cat in the directory

```
/home/adam/Desktop/TomAndJerry
```

and you're currently in the directory

```
/home/adam/Desktop/WorldDominationPlot
```

and you want to capture the filename but not the line number of any instance of the string "cats", and you want the recursion to follow symbolic links if it finds them, you could run either of the following

```
grep -RH "cats" ../TomAndJerry                   #relative directory

grep -RH "cats" /home/adam/Desktop/TomAndJerry   #absolute directory
```

Source:

running "grep --help"

A short introduction to symbolic links, for anyone reading this answer and confused by my reference to them:
https://www.nixtutor.com/freebsd/understanding-symbolic-links/

Comment: Great answer. The extra switches (-rnh) are very helpful, so thanks for suggesting them.

Answer (score 13):

To find name of `files` with `path` recursively containing the particular `string` use below command
for `UNIX`:

```
find . | xargs grep "searched-string"
```

for `Linux`:

```
grep -r "searched-string" .
```

find a file on `UNIX` server

```
find . -type f -name file_name
```

find a file on LINUX server

```
find . -name file_name
```

Answer (score 12):

just the filenames can be useful too

```
grep -r -l "foo" .
```

Answer (score 10):

ag is my favorite way to do this now [github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher](http://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) . It's basically the same thing as ack but with a few more optimizations.

Here's a short benchmark. I clear the cache before each test (cf https://askubuntu.com/questions/155768/how-do-i-clean-or-disable-the-memory-cache )

```
ryan@3G08$ sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
3
ryan@3G08$ time grep -r "hey ya" .

real    0m9.458s
user    0m0.368s
sys 0m3.788s
ryan@3G08:$ sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
3
ryan@3G08$ time ack-grep "hey ya" .

real    0m6.296s
user    0m0.716s
sys 0m1.056s
ryan@3G08$ sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
3
ryan@3G08$ time ag "hey ya" .

real    0m5.641s
user    0m0.356s
sys 0m3.444s
ryan@3G08$ time ag "hey ya" . #test without first clearing cache

real    0m0.154s
user    0m0.224s
sys 0m0.172s
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
grep -R "texthere" *
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a specific content in all files from a directory structure, you may use `find` since it is more clear what you are doing:

```
find -type f -exec grep -l "texthere" {} +
```

Note that `-l` (downcase of L) shows the name of the file that contains the text. Remove it if you instead want to print the match itself. Or use `-H` to get the file together with the match. All together, other alternatives are:

```
find -type f -exec grep -Hn "texthere" {} +
```

Where `-n` prints the line number.

Comment: Up-voted for being the only `find` solution to both avoid unnecessary use of `xargs` and use `+` instead of `\;` with `-exec`, thereby avoiding tons of unnecessary process launches. :-)

Answer (score 7):

This is the one that worked for my case on my current machine (git bash on windows 7):

```
find ./ -type f -iname "*.cs" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "content pattern"
```

I always forget the -print0 and -0 for paths with spaces.

EDIT: My preferred tool is now instead ripgrep: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/releases . It's really fast and has better defaults (like recursive by default). Same example as my original answer but using ripgrep: `rg -g "*.cs" "content pattern"`

Answer (score 6):

`grep -r "texthere" .` *(notice period at the end)*

(^credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1987928/1438029)

---

**Clarification:**

`grep -r "texthere" /` (recursively grep **all** directories and subdirectories)

`grep -r "texthere" .` (recursively grep *these* directories and subdirectories)

## grep recursive

> `grep [options] PATTERN [FILE...]`
>
> [options]
>
> `-R, -r, --recursive`
>
> Read all files under each directory, recursively.
>
> This is equivalent to the `-d recurse` or `--directories=recurse` option.
>
> http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/grep1.html

## grep help

`$ grep --help`

```
$ grep --help |grep recursive
  -r, --recursive           like --directories=recurse
  -R, --dereference-recursive
```

---

### Alternatives

`ack` (http://beyondgrep.com/)

`ag` (http://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)

Answer (score 6):

Throwing my two cents here. As others already mentioned ***grep -r*** doesn't work on every platform. This may sound silly but I always use git.

```
git grep "texthere"
```

Even if the directory is not staged, I just stage it and use git grep.

Answer (score 5):

Below are the command for search a `String` recursively on `Unix` and `Linux` environment.

for `UNIX` command is:

```
find . -name "string to be searched" -exec grep "text" "{}" \;
```

for `Linux` command is:

```
grep -r "string to be searched" .
```

Comment: The use of `find` with `-exec` needs more upvotes over the numerous answers with the non-portable and (slightly) less efficient `-print0 | xargs -0`

Answer (score 5):

In 2018, you want to use `ripgrep` or `the-silver-searcher` because they are way faster than the alternatives.

Here is a directory with 336 first-level subdirectories:

```
% find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l
     336

% time rg -w aggs -g '*.py'
...
rg -w aggs -g '*.py'  1.24s user 2.23s system 283% cpu 1.222 total

% time ag -w aggs -G '.*py$'
...
ag -w aggs -G '.*py$'  2.71s user 1.55s system 116% cpu 3.651 total

% time find ./ -type f -name '*.py' | xargs grep -w aggs
...
find ./ -type f -name '*.py'  1.34s user 5.68s system 32% cpu 21.329 total
xargs grep -w aggs  6.65s user 0.49s system 32% cpu 22.164 total
```

On OSX, this installs `ripgrep`: `brew install ripgrep`. This installs `silver-searcher`: `brew install the_silver_searcher`.

Comment: Speed is important if you need to do this often, but most of us find ourselves only doing this a few times a year at most. Installing the latest spiffy third-party juju tool du jour is overkill and the solutions which haven't changed much since 1978 are good to know regardless.

Comment: I find it highly implausible that a programmer would search for text in a source tree only several times per year. But even from the  viewpoint of usability, `rg` has a considerable edge over cobbling together a recursive grep command from scratch. Using `rg`: `rg foo`. Using unix tools: `find . | xargs grep foo`. And if any of your files has a quote in it, you need to use `find . -print0 | xargs -0 grep foo`. Are you going to remember that if you use this a few times a year?

Comment: You're forgetting `find . -type f -exec grep 'regex' {} +` which indeed is easy to remember if you use these tools with any regularity. But probably you should run `ctags` or `etags` on your source tree anyway if you need to find stuff frequently.

Comment: I've been using ripgrep and it's great.  But silver searcher is fantastic for programmers. +1

Answer (score 4):

In my IBM AIX Server (OS version: AIX 5.2), use:

```
find ./ -type f -print -exec grep -n -i "stringYouWannaFind" {} \;
```

this will print out path/file name and  relative line number in the file like:

./inc/xxxx_x.h

2865: /**   Description  : stringYouWannaFind   */

anyway,it works for me : )

Answer (score 3):

For a list of available flags:

```
grep --help
```

Returns all matches for the regexp *texthere* in the current directory, with the corresponding line number:

```
grep -rn "texthere" .
```

Returns all matches for *texthere*, starting at the root directory, with the corresponding line number and ignoring case:

```
grep -rni "texthere" /
```

**flags used here:**

- `-r` recursive
- `-n` print line number with output
- `-i` ignore case

Answer (score 2):

Note that `find . -type f | xargs grep whatever` sorts of solutions will run into "Argument list to long" errors when there are too many files matched by find.

The best bet is `grep -r` but if that isn't available, use `find . -type f -exec grep -H whatever {} \;` instead.

Comment: Huh?  `xargs` is specifically a workaround for the "Argument list too long" problem.

Comment: Well, no - xargs is _specifically_ for converting a pipe of arguments to an arglist, but yes, it is true that modern xargs _when used with -s and/or -L_ can deal with very long arglists by breaking into multiple command invocations, but it isn't configured that way by default (and wasn't in any of the above responses).  As an example:
`find . -type f | xargs -L 100 grep whatever`

Comment: Which platform would that be on?  [POSIX `xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xargs.html) is standardized to have this behavior out of the box. *"The `xargs` utility shall limit the command line length such that when the command line is invoked, the combined argument and environment lists ... shall not exceed {ARG_MAX}-2048 bytes."*

Comment: Hm.  While the gnu docs are less clear than posix on this basis, and I no longer have access to the machine that caused me to make this statement, I cannot confirm my original interpretation on any current implementation.  Recursive grep is, of course, still preferable if available, but there's little reason to avoid the xargs recipe (do use -H for the grep to avoid the final invocation of grep getting passed only a single filename, though).

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you're trying to write

```
grep myText $(find .)
```

and this may be something else helpful if you want to find the files grep hit

```
grep myText $(find .) | cut -d : -f 1 | sort | uniq
```

Comment: It's very intuitive: for example: grep -i acc $(find . -name "execution*.*")

Comment: This runs into several common beginner problems for file names with whitespace in them etc. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 and https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#backticks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive (tested lightly with bash and sh) function that traverses all subfolders of a given folder ($1) and using `grep` searches for given string ($3) in given files ($2):

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/sh

cd "$1"

loop () {
    for i in *
    do
        if [ -d "$i" ]
        then
            # echo entering "$i"
            cd "$i"
            loop "$1" "$2"
        fi
    done

    if [ -f "$1" ]
    then
        grep -l "$2" "$PWD/$1"
    fi

    cd ..
}

loop "$2" "$3"
```

Running it and an example output:

```
$ sh script start_folder filename search_string
/home/james/start_folder/dir2/filename
```

Answer (score 2):

For .gz files, recursively scan all files and directories
Change file type or put *

```
find . -name \*.gz -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep "STRING"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a quick and dirty search of *.txt files if the @christangrant answer is too much to type :-)

`grep -r texthere .|grep .txt`

Answer (score 1):

Get the first matched files from grep command and get all the files don't contain some word, but input files for second grep comes from result files of first grep command.

```
grep -l -r --include "*.js" "FIRSTWORD" * | xargs grep "SECONDwORD"
grep -l -r --include "*.js" "FIRSTWORD" * | xargs grep -L "SECONDwORD"
```

dc0fd654-37df-4420-8ba5-6046a9dbe406

```
grep -l -r --include "*.js" "SEARCHWORD" * | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}' | xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo {}; grep -l -r --include "*.html" -w --include=*.js -e {} *;  echo '''
```

5319778a-cec2-444d-bcc4-53d33821fedb

```
grep "SEARCH_STRING" *.log | grep -e "http" -e "https" | awk '{print $NF}' | uniq
```

ce91d131-a5c2-4cc8-b836-1461feee6cdb

Here's how you can modify the command to extract the value of messageName:

```
grep -m 2 "In sendMessage:: " *LOGFILE.log | grep -o -e "messageName=[^,]*" | cut -d= -f2 | sort | uniq | tee >(echo "Number of unique values: $(wc -l)")

grep "In Message:: " *messaging.log | grep -o -e "messageName=[^,]*" | cut -d= -f2 | sort | uniq | while read -r messageName; do grep -m 1 "In  sendMessage:: .*messageName=${messageName}" *logfile.log | head -n 1; done
```

I want to use run below grep command over above files
2. files to be sorted in descending order based on their update time and not matching the .gz format

```
grep "org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader at" $(ls -lrth | grep -i opti | awk '{print $NF}')
      grep -A 15 "request to URL : SEARCH" $(ls -lth | grep "common" | grep -v ".gz"  | awk '{print $NF}')
```

command to create a new file from the first occurrence to the last occurrence.

```
sed -n '/14 Jan 2023/,/14 Jan 2023/p' common.log > common_1day.log
```

Today modified files,

```
ls -lrth $(find . -type f -name "*.log" -newermt "$(date -R -d 'today 00:00')" -print)
grep "CID" $(find . -type f -name "*.log" -newermt "$(date -R -d 'today 00:00')" -print)
zgrep "SEARCH" $(find . -type f -newermt "$(date -R -d 'today 00:00')" -print)
ls -lrth $(find . -type f -name "*" -newermt "$(date -R -d 'today 00:00')" -print)
less +G $(find . -type f -name "*LOG_FILE.log" -newermt "$(date -R -d 'today 00:00')" -print)
grep Async $(find . -type f -name "*" -newermt "2023-04-14 00:00:00" ! -newermt "2023-04-16 00:00:00" -print)
```

Find commands

```
find . -type f -not -path "*/target/*" -name "log4j2.xml" -exec grep -H '<Async name="' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

On Solaris (and likely other old Unixes)

ggrep -r "$yourtext" $directory