# GitHub advanced search default behaviour

Tags: github

I'm new to Github and just want to browse through repos to find interesting ones.
I want, say, all ruby repos with more than 100 followers.
I go to [advanced search](https://github.com/search) and try ["followers:100"](https://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=ruby&q=followers%3A100&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&x=0&y=0)
and get only repos with EXACTLY 100 followers (4 at the moment).
That differs from what i expect to be default behavior  - find repos with 100 **or more** followers (more like Stackoverflow search works).
I am quite frustrated, because I can't get what is expected to be basic search functionality from a very popular site, and that makes me think that I'm obviously not understanding something very simple  (because I think it is not possible for Github not to have such functions).
So is there a way for me to get the desired result?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update January 2013 (source: "[**A whole new code search**](https://github.com/blog/1381-a-whole-new-code-search)")

[`followers:>100`](https://github.com/search?q=followers:%3E100&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=)

(intervals are supported: [`followers:100..150`](https://github.com/search?q=followers:100..150&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults))

---

Original answer (April 2011)

```
 followers:[100 TO *]
```

should do what you want: see your query with [100 or more followers](https://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=ruby&q=followers:%5B100%20TO%20*%5D&repo=&langOverride=&x=0&y=0&start_value=1).
(Note: the "`TO`" needs to be in uppercase)

(Source: [New and Improved Search](https://github.com/blog/309-new-and-improved-search))

> For example, we can search:
>
> - for people with a username fuzzily similar to ‘`chacon`’
> - who use `Ruby` as their primary language,
> - have at least 5 repos and
> - at least one follower:

[image: example of GutHub query]

Comment: I saw your question on GitHub support (http://support.github.com/discussions/site/3525-advanced-search-uderstanding): maybe they will confirm my own answer here.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll add a link there.

Comment: @SiweiShen: mainly, I learn from the Git and GitHub *other* gurus on Stack Overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/github/topusers, and  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/topusers)

Answer (score 1):

You might also like the [Hubscovery](http://hubscovery.com) application. A simple search interface for Github.

Comment: seems that this website is down, I can't open it in China, March 22th, 2012

Comment: It works here. But, if down in China, you can easily install [your own](https://github.com/jschoolcraft/Hubscovery), the software that runs it, is Open Source.