# Github search results as RSS feed

Tags: github

Is there a trick to get the [search results of GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740454/github-advanced-search-default-behaviour) as RSS feed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have hacked up something with [hubscovery](https://github.com/jschoolcraft/Hubscovery) and sinatra. Similar to [hubscovery.com](http://hubscovery.com). The output is a simple RSS feed.

Comment: Both links are broken (now).