# Get sorted github repository search results by "some" attribute(the number of forks or stars)

Tags: git, github

How to get github search results sorted by the number of forks or stars?

I need this feature to demonstrate which project is the hottest among those that target the similar task/function/feature.

I notice github do offer the advanced search [here](https://github.com/search), but how to write the query? Say, I wonder the top 10 forked django plugin apps. What the query looks like? I tried 
"django- fork:" or even "django- fork:>500", it doesn't work. (here we use 'django-' since most django plugin apps has such prefix)

Comment: I have updated the update of my answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update of the Update (February 2013, source "**[Sortable Stars](https://github.com/blog/1410-sortable-stars)**"):

> Starting today you can sort your [starred repositories](https://github.com/stars) by when you starred them or when the repositories were last updated.

[image]

So the sort criteria is now visible.

---

Update January 2013 (source: "[**A whole new code search**](https://github.com/blog/1381-a-whole-new-code-search)")

Searching by number of forks seems now to return a result ordered by number of forks

[`django- forks:>500`](https://github.com/search?q=django-%20forks:%3E500&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=)

This is confirmed by the blog post "[Sorting through Search Results](https://github.com/blog/1396-sorting-through-search-results)" (January 31, 2013):

> If you're searching through repositories, you can sort by stars, forks, or recently-updated

---

(Original answer: Sept. 2012)

I don't see any sort option in GitHub advanced search.

The forks: filter is to indicate a precise number of fork, like [this query](https://github.com/search?q=django-%20forks:100%20fork:&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&language=) would display the 4 repos with 100 forks for "`django-`". But that doesn't display *all* repo above 100 forks, and that doesn't sort them.

Comment: Yes, I found the github only support "Exact search". In your case, is it possible to search the repo with the number of forks > 100?

Comment: @hushwings at first glance, it doesn't seem to be possible

Comment: if github cannot support "<" ">" predicate, I think the prefix search is almost useless. How could you count on the user know the exact repo #forks(:forks), #followers(:followsers), and even size(:size). So disappointed!

Answer (score 0):

GitHub supports the "Lucene query syntax".

See @VonC's answer here:

[GitHub advanced search default behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740454/github-advanced-search-default-behaviour)

and

http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html

But Lucene doesn't support ordering.