# GitHub API popular repos

Tags: github

Do users have access to the "most starred" or "most watched" repositories, through the API? Similar to these pages.

[**github.com/popular/starred**](http://github.com/popular/starred)

[**github.com/languages/shell/most_watched**](http://github.com/languages/Shell/most_watched)

Comment: I tried to complete/update the answer.

Comment: This is the one you want , but not sure Search API provide these options https://github.com/search?q=stars%3A%3E%3D0&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No: this is user-centric, meaning you get the repo starred *by users, or by a given user*.

And don't forget what you are calling ["watch" is now "star"](http://developer.github.com/changes/2012-9-5-watcher-api/).

> What used to be known as “Watching” is now “Starring”.
>   Starring is basically a way to bookmark interesting repositories.
>   Watching is a way to indicate that you want to receive email or web notifications on a Repository.

---

While the search GUI now exposes "stars" as a sort order (see "[Get sorted github repository search results by “some” attribute(the number of forks or stars)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241873/get-sorted-github-repository-search-results-by-some-attributethe-number-of-fo/12241932#12241932)", February 2013), the [search API](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/) (a port from V2) is the only one mentioning ["stars" as a sort order for repositories](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories).

```
GET /legacy/repos/search/:keyword?sort=stars
```

(this should [work both for public GH and GHE: GitHub for enterprise](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-1182?focusedCommentId=440704&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-440704), but requires a keyword, and does not follow the v3 pagination pattern. This method returns up to 100 results per page and pages can be fetched using the start_page parameter.)

[Aditya Mehta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10702098/aditya-mehta) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716053/github-api-popular-repos/13718914?noredirect=1#comment105340881_13718914):

> Here is the **query to find repositories with the highest number of stars, sorted by star count**.
>   [`api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E1&sort=stars`](https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E1&sort=stars)

Comment: Adding to the previous answer, here will be the query to find repositories with the highest number of stars, sorted by star count. https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E1&sort=stars

Comment: @AdityaMehta Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.