# GitHub : Is it possible to search inside code and sort by stars

Tags: search, github

I'm not sure if this is the right forum for this question. Saw quite a few Q&A related to search on GitHub, hence posting here. 
E.g. [Search code inside a Github project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3616221/781695)

GitHub advanced search allows terms like `stars:>100` but the query term is restricted to repository names only. Is it possible to search for a term inside the files (code) & sort by stars? My aim is to see which popular repos are using a particular keyword in their code. It would be very useful if GitHub's advanced search options for `Repositories` worked for `Code` also.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/13718914/6309 help?

Answer (score 23):

It is **not possible** to sort by stars when searching inside code.

From an e-mail from github.com support:

> Code search does not support sorting by number of stars, but I will definitely add your +1 to that suggestion internally! I can't say if or when a change will happen, but your feedback is in the right hands.

---

You may want to vote for this feature: [Add Stars count filter](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/8578).
The feedback is related to this announcement: [Improving GitHub code search](https://github.blog/2021-12-08-improving-github-code-search/)

Comment: that is a shame. Not only one, but two reasons: a) it is basic functional requirement to sort hundreds of result by some quality rank. b) As for any result item, there is a single star number attribute, and it is simple to get, there is no technical difficulty to do this.