# Finding popular open source projects on Github using a specific library

Tags: github, open-source

I looked through Github search docs for [repos](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-for-repositories/#search-based-on-the-contents-of-a-repository) and [code](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/) and I am not sure if it is possible.

I want to find popular open source projects that use a specific library to see how they handle particular design patterns. In my case, I am looking for popular Android projects that use [Dagger 2](https://github.com/google/dagger).

I tried using a [code search](https://github.com/search?l=Gradle&p=1&q=com.google.dagger%3Adagger-android-processor%3A&type=Code) for `com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:` in .gradle which gives me 14k+ results for mostly unpopular projects. I would basically just want to sort by forks/stars, which is not an option as far as I can see.

If this is not possible with Github's search I am happy with any alternative.

Answer (score 2):

For projects that use one of the package managers ​​which is [supported by GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/articles/listing-the-projects-that-depend-on-a-repository) (RubyGemsm, NPM, PyPI, Maven, Nuget), you can use [ghtopdep](https://github.com/github-tooling/ghtopdep)

Related [issue](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1537)

Answer (score 0):

A *Code* search would *not* allow sorting through *repository* stars ([as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51036797/6309))

Maybe:

- [using a BigQuery](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bigquery-github/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) would allow using that criteria ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42930963/6309))
- or [using GraphQL](https://developer.github.com/v4/)