# how to check popular repos and other stats in github?

Tags: github

I 'm not able to find the way of finding out which repos have most stars , most forked and according to each language. There is no direct link to statistics and when I go to stars , it only shows my stared repos.  Where can I find that?

Answer (score 2):

The page GitHub/explore is a good starting point: https://github.com/explore

From there, you can see repositories trending: https://github.com/trending?since=monthly

And you can filter by language.

But both aren't sorted by stars. As I mention in "[Get sorted github repository search results by “some” attribute(the number of forks or stars)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12241932/6309)", you can do a search and sort by stars.
This is detailed in the blog post "[Sorting through Search Results](https://github.com/blog/1396-sorting-through-search-results)" (January 2013)

For instance, here are the most starred repos in Go language:

https://github.com/search?l=Go&o=desc&q=go&ref=advsearch&s=stars&type=Repositories

Comment: Perfect. That is what I was looking for.
https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=stars%3A%3E1&s=stars&type=Repositories  For javascript :p