# A public Github repo not found via search

Tags: search, github, solr-query-syntax

using the following search query...

https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AOpeningDesign%2FOpeningDesign+GET&p=1&ref=searchbar&type=Code&l=

..on this public repo: https://github.com/OpeningDesign/OpeningDesign

nothing shows up.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Just tried it with your example and a couple of others - and it doesn't work. Looks like code search with repo: and other options doesn't work at the moment. I suggest you report this to GitHub support folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update January 24th, 2013: source "[A Whole New Code Search](https://github.com/blog/1381-a-whole-new-code-search)"

The same query [`repo:OpeningDesign/OpeningDesign GET`](https://github.com/search?q=repo:OpeningDesign/OpeningDesign%20GET&p=1&ref=searchbar&type=Code&l=) now returns result!

The search index must have been updated when then new search engine has been deployed ([elasticsearch.org](http://www.elasticsearch.org/community/))

---

Original answer (January 6th, 2013)

Considering that:

- any request on the ruby/ruby repo *works* (as mentioned in "[Search code inside a Github project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616221/search-code-inside-a-github-project)")
- any request on [`OpeningDesign/OpeningDesign`](https://github.com/OpeningDesign/OpeningDesign) doesn't work,

it seems to be an indexation issue.

After their recent [fileservers issues](https://github.com/blog/1364-downtime-last-saturday), this could be a side-effect.
As Iven points out, [GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) should be able to clarify this.

---

The support did clarify (07 January 2013):

> **We have stopped adding newly pushed code into our codesearch index**.
>
> The volume of code has outgrown our current search index, and we are working on moving to a more scalable search architecture.
> I'm sorry for the annoyance.
> We do not have an estimate for when this new search index will be up and running, but when it is ready a blog post will be published ([GitHub blog](https://github.com/blog))

Comment: zonks... looks major.  Thanks @VonC

Comment: Update from github: *"Hello Ryan,

We have stopped adding newly pushed code into our codesearch index. The volume of code has outgrown our current search index, and we are working on moving to a more scalable search architecture. I'm sorry for the annoyance. We do not have an estimate for when this new search index will be up and running, but when it is ready a blog post will be published (https://github.com/blog)."*

Comment: @RyanSchultz Thank you for the feedback. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.