# PHP function unique_id(), where can I see the code for the function?

Tags: php

I couldn't find the actual function's code as I am interested in how it creates the id, e.g. where it gets the time from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're still interested in the source, it's in the public git repository:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/uniqid.c

```
gettimeofday((struct timeval *) &tv, (struct timezone *) NULL);
sec = (int) tv.tv_sec;
usec = (int) (tv.tv_usec % 0x100000);

/* The max value usec can have is 0xF423F, so we use only five hex
* digits for usecs.
*/
if (more_entropy) {
    spprintf(&uniqid, 0, "%s%08x%05x%.8F", prefix, sec, usec, php_combined_lcg(TSRMLS_C) * 10);
} else {
    spprintf(&uniqid, 0, "%s%08x%05x", prefix, sec, usec);
}

RETURN_STRING(uniqid, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Which function? I don't believe there's a `unique_id()` function in PHP. The code for `uniqid()` is in [ext/standard/uniqid.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/uniqid.c).

You can search for this kind of thing on Github by narrowing down the repository. For example, searching for [repo:php/php-src uniqid](https://github.com/search?q=+uniqid+repo%3Aphp%2Fphp-src&p=1&ref=searchbar&type=Code&l=) will find references to uniqid in the php repo.

There's an example of this, and other Github search syntax, in [the answer to this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616221/search-code-inside-a-github-project).

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the source code for uniqid() in
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/uniqid.c

Answer (score 0):

This might help from the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

It explains the uniqueness is taken from the time in microseconds.

Comment: It doesn't give me the actual code though, I am looking to see how that function is made